# Problemas de cálculo con operaciones con números con decimales

Tags: vb.net

Buenas tardes.

Estoy trabajando (en VB .Net 4.6) con un facturador de ventas y tengo el siguiente inconveniente, al querer realizar el cálculo: 100.02-100=0.02, obtengo:
Caso 1: `100.02-100 -> 0.019999999999996021 (Double)` X
Caso 2: `CDec(100.02-100) -> 0.019999999999996 (Decimal)` X
Caso 3: `cdec(100.02)-cdec(100) -> 0.02 (Decimal)` √

Si uso tipos de datos `System.Single` tengo estas diferencias, pero si uso `System.Decimal` es matar un mosquito con un cañon. Sólo utilizo 2 decimales significativos.

¿Es un 'error' de esta versión del framework? ¿Sí o sí debo utilizar tipos de datos `System.Decimal` para evitar las diferencias al operar con `System.Single` y `System.Double`?

Comment: No es tardes; es la manana (aqui in California). Yo creo es el mejor siempre usar Decimal para moneda. Es Decimal menos efficaz? Tal vez, pero es vale la pena. Disculpeme por mi espanol bastante mala.

Comment: Usa `System.Decimal` :)

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, duda aclarada. Saludos.

Comment: **"System.Decimal es matar un mosquito con un cañon"** - `Decimal` está pensado exactamente para este tipo de casos, yo diría mas bien es **matar una mosca con un matamoscas**

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta a tu problema la puedes encontrar en este [otro hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%C3%A9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%C3%A1lculos-aritm%C3%A9ticos-correctamente).

Para evitar problemas con los redondeos lo más recomendable en `.NET` es usar el tipo `Decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

No es un error de framework sino tienes que ver con la precision decimal del tipo de datos

Si necesitas realizar un calculo y solo obtener una determinada precision en decimales usa el

[Math.Round()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx)

De esta forma al calculo le indicas la cantidad de decimales que necesitas

```
Dim result As Decimal = Math.Round(CDec(100.02-100), 2)
```