# ¿Cómo puedo redondear y mostrar en 2 decimales en JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

No se como podría redondear y mostrar en dos decimales. Aunque he utilizado para el redondeo la clase Math.round pero no he podido solucionar esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el código

Bean:

```
private double igv;
private double subtotal;    

public void agregar() {
    subtotal+=Math.round((det1.getCantidad()*det1.getPreciocompra()/1.18)*100.0)/100.0;
            igv+=Math.round(((det1.getCantidad()*det1.getPreciocompra()/1.18)*0.18)*100.0)/100.0;
}
```

Facelets:

```
<p:columnGroup type="footer">                              
<p:row>                              
  <p:column colspan="4" style="text-align:right" footerText="SUB-TOTAL" />
  <p:column footerText="#{entradaBean.subtotal}" style="text-align: right"   />                           
</p:row>  
 <p:row>                              
  <p:column colspan="4" style="text-align:right" footerText="IGV:" />
  <p:column footerText="#{entradaBean.igv}" style="text-align: right" />                           
   </p:row>                              
 <p:row>                              
  <p:column colspan="4" style="text-align:right" footerText="Monto Total:" />
  <p:column footerText="S/.#{entradaBean.montototal}" style="text-align: right" />
  </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
```

Answer (score 5):

Primero que nada, no utilices `double`, es mejor utilizar `BigDecimal` puesto que ofrece mejor precisión al trabajar con estos números. Sobretodo, deberías utilizar `BigDecimal` al trabajar en operaciones financieras como la que muestras en tu ejemplo.

De todas maneras, si es que no vas a cambiar el tipo de dato de tus variables, lo que debes hacer es utilizar `<f:convertNumber>`. Esta etiqueta te permite dar el formato al número como cantidad de posiciones decimales, moneda, y otros. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.subtotal}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
</h:outputText>
```

El campo `pattern` se basa en los patrones que soporta la clase [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). Para comprender el patrón de arriba, se deben entender los siguientes símbolos:

- `#`: cualquier dígito, opcional.
- `.`: punto decimal.
- `0`: cualquier dígito, obligatorio.

El patrón utilizado `#0.00` significa que el número puede tener uno o más digitos en la parte entera, luego el punto decimal y por último dos números decimales de manera obligatoria.

Basado en tu código Facelets, deberías cambiarlo de esta manera:

```
<p:row>
    <p:column colspan="4" style="text-align:right"
        footerText="SUB-TOTAL" />
    <p:column style="text-align: right">
         <f:facet name="footer">
             <h:outputText value="#{entradaBean.subtotal}">
                <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
            </h:outputText>
         </f:facet>
    </p:column>
    <!-- lo mismo para los otros campos -->
</p:row>
```

Comment: me genera este error voy a investigarlo  Parent not an instance of ValueHolder: org.primefaces.component.column

Comment: edite mi pregunta y puse el código no se porque no muestra ???

Comment: Eso es porque no está indentado como código que reconocería Markdown, y por defecto evita el renderizado de cualquier código con estructura HTML para evitar problemas de inyección. Acabo de editar el texto para que se pueda ver el código.

Comment: ok gracias Luiggi

Comment: Respuesta actualizada. Por favor revísalo y dime si aún hay problemas.

Comment: no muestra el resultado del subtotal y si añado  <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" /> me genera el mismo error  <f:convertNumber> Parent not an instance of ValueHolder: org.primefaces.component.column

Comment: Disculpa, hubo un error en el código publicado. Ya lo corregí. Esto debería solucionar el problema.

Comment: si esta pero el problema esta en la precisión del subtotal conforme va aumentando se va perdiendo la precisión del resultado en el subtotal

Comment: Para obtener una mejor precisión utiliza `BigDecimal`, no `double`. Un concepto general de trabajar con `double` (y lo mismo sucede con `float`) es que no es preciso en operaciones decimales. Hay más detalle al respecto [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/227).

Answer (score 1):

Nunca pero nunca utilices el formato `Double` cuando hagas cuentas financieras, los montos no cuadrarán pues Java en ese caso prioriza eficiencia sobre precisión. Utiliza `BigDecimal`

```
 BigDecimal valor = new BigDecimal(37.288136);

 BigDecimal valorRedondeado = valor.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

Donde:

- ROUND_HALF_UP indica que se redondee si es igual o mayor a 5 en el último dígito de la parte decimal luego redondeable.
- 2 es el número de decimales que deseas.

Por lo que el resultado sería de `37.29`

Espero te sirva y aceptes mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

> Puedes cambiar la , por . o darle mas decimales si quieres , funciona muy parecido a los format que uno realiza con datos tipo Date

```
 private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(",##");

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            double input = 32.123456;
            System.out.println("double : " + input);
            System.out.println("double : " + df2.format(input));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si se esta usando primefaces, se podia usar primefaces extensions
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/inputNumber/basicUsage.jsf