# ¿Porqué hay ocasiones en las que python calcula de forma errónea operaciones matemáticas?

Tags: python

```
a = 1000000000

for i in range(1000000):
    a += 0.000001

a = a - 1000000000

print a
```

El resultado debería ser a = 1, sin embargo da a = 0.953674316406, a que se debe esto ? Eh visto que pasa en otro tipo de cálculos también.

Comment: Por favor, revisa [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente) y entenderás porqué se producen estos problemas. Si quieres precisión absoluta con decimales, prueba con el módulo `decimal` de python.

Comment: Un clásico que me encanta: `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` :)

Comment: Dale, muchas gracias !!