# Coordenadas de la aguja del minutero

Tags: javascript, matemáticas

Quiero saber cómo se hace una función en *javaScript* que devuelva las **coordenadas en determinado minuto**. Las coordenadas centrales son el centro del reloj, así que pueden ser negativas.

En Microsiervos encontré [un enlace](http://www.microsiervos.com/archivo/gadgets/scope-watch-reloj-coordenadas.html), que hace paralelismo a lo que yo pregunto, es un reloj que te da la hora en *coordenadas*.

Estoy probando la división o la resta, pero no me sale.

```
function(minutos)
{
    var x=0,y=0
    x=minutos*60
    y=x-12
    return [x,y]
}
```

**Edito:**

Mirando algunas respuestas he visto algo extraño: ¿Por qué usar **coseno**, si es posible extraer en valor usando **seno**?

[image: Fórmula pi medio]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Según esta página de [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19558/how-do-i-find-a-point-given-an-angle-and-distance-to-it) y esta otra de [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143932/calculate-point-given-x-y-angle-and-distance) (ambas en inglés), las coordenadas de un punto se pueden calcular conociendo

- El punto de origen (el centro del reloj);
- La distancia a recorrer (el tamaño del minutero); y
- El ángulo (suponemos 0 es la derecha y partir de ahí seguimos el sentido de las agujas del reloj)

Partiendo de que le centro del reloj tiene las coordenadas `[0,0]`, entonces la fórmula para las coordenadas del nuevo punto sería algo como esto:

```
nuevas_coordenadas = [  distancia * coseno(angulo)  ,  - distancia * seno(angulo)  ]
```

> Realmente pone que debería ser `distancia * seno(angulo)`, pero me sale correcto sólo si lo pongo como negativo. Quizás entendí mal, pero con el `-` funciona.

Para el seno y coseno podemos usar las funciones [`sin()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin) y [`cos()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos) de JavaScript, ambas toman como parámetro un ángulo en radianes. Y eso nos lleva al segundo punto: el ángulo en radianes. Sabemos que una circunferencia tiene 2π radianes, y que hay 60 minutos en una hora, por lo que para cada minuto, el ángulo será algo como esto:

```
ángulo   =   2π * minutos / 60   =   π * minutos / 30
```

Para el valor de π podemos usar la propiedad [`PI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI). Pero tiene un poco de truco, como la dirección es a la derecha, eso significa que estamos en el minuto 15 de primeras, por lo que habrá que ajustar un poco el ángulo:

```
ángulo   =   π * (minutos - 15) / 30
```

Y poniendo todo eso junto, nos quedaría algo como esto:

```
function calculaCoordenadasMinuto(minuto) {

    var distancia = 1; // supongo que el minutero tiene una distancia de 1
    var angulo    = Math.PI * minuto / 30;

    return [ distancia * Math.cos(angulo), -distancia * Math.sin(angulo) ];
}
```

---

Aquí dejo un ejemplo (usando segundos en lugar de minutos, pero la idea es similar):

```js
var pos = 0;

function calculaCoordenadasMinuto(minuto) {
  var angulo    = Math.PI * (minuto - 15) / 30;
  return [ Math.cos(angulo), -Math.sin(angulo) ];
}

setInterval(function() {
  pos++;
  var coords  = calculaCoordenadasMinuto(pos);
  var segundo = document.getElementById("segundo");
  segundo.style.marginLeft = (50 * coords[0]) + "px";
  segundo.style.marginTop  = (-50 * coords[1]) + "px";
}, 1000);
```

```css
#reloj {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#eee;
  border-radius:100%;
}

#reloj::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  width:2px;
  height:2px;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  background:black;
  border-radius:100%;
}

#segundo {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  width:3px;
  height:3px;
  background:red;
  margin-top:-50px;
  margin-left:0;
  border-radius:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="reloj">
  <div id="segundo"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Para poder responder esa pregunta, imagina que el reloj es un círculo, para conocer las coordenadas es necesaria la **función seno**, y la función seno necesita del **número pi**, y una manera de calcular *pi* es mediante la **función arcoseno**.

Este es el artículo del [Número pi en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_%CF%80), en él se pone la fórmula de cómo calcular *pi* mediante el *arcoseno*.

[image: Fórmulas de arcoseno.]

La fórmula de la *función seno* sería esta.

[image: Fórmula de seno.]

Pensando un poco, teniendo en cuenta que una vuelta completa del círculo tiene **360 grados**, y que una hora tiene **60 minutos**, pude resolver el problema, y además lo hice de esta manera porque desconfiaba de los valores de las funciones estándar de *javascript*, al desconocer su **código fuente**, debe estar en alguna parte del [motor V8 (Wikipedia)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(motor_JavaScript)), quise estar seguro de dar valores correctos.

El código final sería este.

```js
function asin(x)
{
  var b=1,c=Math.pow,e=-1
  var a=x
  var e = undefined
  for(var i=1;e!=a;i+=2)
  {
      e=a
      b*=i/(i+1);a+=b*c(x,i+2)/(i+2)
  }
  return [a,(i-1)/2]
}
function pi()
{
  return asin(1/2)[0]*6
}
function sin(d,f)
{
  var a=0,b=1,c=Math.pow,e=-1,g=pi()
  var e = undefined
  if(f=="deg"){d*g/180}
  d-=2*g*Math.floor(d/(g*2))
  for(var i=1;e!=a;i+=4)
  {
      e=a
      a+=c(d,i+0)/b;b*=(i+1);b*=(i+2)
      a-=c(d,i+2)/b;b*=(i+3);b*=(i+4)
  }
  return [a,(i-1)/4]
}
function reloj(minutos)
{
  var ángulo=minutos/60*2*pi()
  return [sin(ángulo)[0],sin(ángulo+pi()/2)[0]]
}

for(var i=7;i<60;i+=11)
{
  var resultado = reloj(i)
  console.log(
    "minutos:", i,
    ", x: ", resultado[0],
    ", y: ", resultado[1]
  )
}
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar `Math.PI`, `Math.sin`, etc. No es una idea seria _desconfiar_ de las funciones estandar de javascript ya que estan bien probadas, seguramente mejor probadas que cualquier otra que tu o yo podamos hacer, ademas de que probablemente utilizen el procesador matematico del CPU.

Answer (score 8):

Probado en Node.js:

```
var Log = require( 'console' ).log;

function point( min ) {    
  var rad = 2 * Math.PI * ( min / 60 ) - ( ( 2 * Math.PI ) / 4 );

  return [ Math.cos( rad ), -Math.sin( rad ) ];
}

Log( point( 0 ) );
Log( point( 15 ) );
Log( point( 30 ) );
Log( point( 45 ) );
Log( point( 60 ) );
```

EDITO

Explicación detallada del *meollo* del asunto: `var rad = 2 * Math.PI * ( min / 60 ) - ( ( 2 * Math.PI ) / 4 );`

```
2 * Math.PI * ( min / 60 )
```

Transformamos los minutos en radianes. `( min / 60 )` nos resulta en los *grados* equivalentes a los minutos indicados. Para convertirlo en radianes (las funciones matemáticas implicadas, `Math.sin` y `Math.cos`, trabajan con radianes, no con grados), se multiplican por 2Pi.

```
- ( ( 2 * Math.PI ) / 4 )
```

Las funciones `seno` y `coseno` son **funciones periódicas**, con resultados comprendidos entre -1 y 1, ambos incluidos ( [-1, 1] ). Esa expresión prepara el anterior resultado ( el angulo en radianes que estamos procesando ) para que las salidas de `Math.sin()` y `Math.cos()` nos resulten útiles. Digamos que *escala* los radianes para que el resultado de `Math.sin()` y `Math.cos()` encajen en nuestro espacio completo de la circunferencia.

**EDITO 1** para adecuarlo a la nueva versión de la pregunta.

**Explicación de porque es posible esa sustitución**

Como dije anteriormente, `seno( )` y `coseno( )` son funciones **periodicas**, es decir, sus valores se repiten con el tiempo. Lo que no dijimos es su periodo, lo que tardan en repetir sus valores. En ambos casos, su periodo es PI / 2.
Pensemoslo con detenimiento ... **mismo** rango de valores de resultado ... **mismo** periodo ... esto nos sugiere que **ambas** funciones han de ser muy similares, variando unicamente el desplazamiento sobre el eje X del resultado.

En esta gráfica tan chula, tomada de la Wikipedia, se aprecia todo muy bien. El eje X representa el **angulo en radianes**, mientras que el eje Y representa la salida de la función (el valor que devuelve).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fuente: [Wikipedia, Trigonometría](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometr%C3%ADa)

Si miramos la gráfica, lo vemos todo claro:

> El **coseno** de un ángulo (línea verde), no es más que el **seno** (línea roja) del mismo angulo *desfasado* PI/2 radianes; es decir, el **coseno** *va por detrás*; en un momento dado cualquiera, siendo X el seno de un angulo A, el coseno es **exactamente** el mismo que el seno de ( A - ( PI / 2 ) ), ambos en radiantes.
>   En la gráfica, se aprecia claramente que `seno( PI ) == 0`, que es exactamente `coseno( PI / 2 ) == 0`. Igual para los demás valores. Si lo hacemos en grados, el **coseno** *va 45º por detrás* del **seno**.

A continuación, puesto que la gráfica no tiene apenas valores, muestro algunos, para comprobarlo:

> Grados: 0, radianes: 0, seno: 0, coseno: 1
>
> Grados: 45, radianes: 0.7854, seno: 0.8509, coseno: 0.7071
>
> Grados: 90, radianes: 1.5708, seno: 0.894, coseno: 0
>
> Grados: 135, radianes: 2.3562, seno: 0.0884, coseno: -0.7071
>
> Grados: 180, radianes: 3.1416, seno: -0.8012, coseno: -1
>
> Grados: 225, radianes: 3.927, seno: -0.9301, coseno: -0.7071
>
> Grados: 270, radianes: 4.7124, seno: -0.176, coseno: 0
>
> Grados: 315, radianes: 5.4978, seno: 0.7451, coseno: 0.7071
>
> Grados: 360, radianes: 6.2832, seno: 0.9589, coseno: 1

**EDITO 2**

¿ Porqué no coinciden los valores ? según la parrafada de antes, deberían coincidir, ¿ no ?

Recomiendo hechar un ojo a [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%C3%A9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%C3%A1lculos-aritm%C3%A9ticos-correctamente)

En esta tabla de ejemplo, además de lo anterior, y como veremos en el código, parte de la culpa la tiene el uso de la función `Number.toFixed( )`, que descarta decimales. En este caso concreto, no ocurre nada, pero... si tenemos que *escalar* el resultado (multiplicarlo por algún número), la imprecisión puede ser suficientemente grande como para producir **artefactos** no deseados, sobre todo en temas gráficos.

**FIN EDITO 2**

El código en Node.js, muy simple, por si alguien quiere comprobarlo:

```
var log = require( 'console' ).log;
var grad,
      rad;
for( grad = 0; grad < 365; grad += 45 ) {
  rad = grad * Math.PI / 180;
  log( "Grados: %d, radianes: %d, seno: %d, coseno: %d", grad, rad.toFixed( 4 ), Math.sin( grad ).toFixed( 4 ), Math.cos( rad ).toFixed( 4 ) );
}
```

Se aprecia que `cos( 90º ) == 0`, que es exactamente lo mismo que `sen( 0 ) == 0`; Lo dicho anteriormente, el coseno de un angulo es el seno de `angulo - PI/2`; o, dicho de otra forma, el coseno *var* 45º *por detrás*.

Ya sabemos porqué es posible esa sustitución.

**Respuesta** a la nueva pregunta.

Hablo por mí, los demás tendrán sus propias razonas. Usé el **coseno** porqué es lo que viene en todos los ejemplo que he visto en Internet. No se me ocurrio hacerlo asi, sin el coseno ;-)

**EDITO 2**

Teniendo en cuenta el tema de la precisión numérica expuesto mas arriba, resulta que **si hay un motivo para usar el coseno**.

Pensemos:

- ángulo X -> impreciso.
- PI -> impreciso.

Entonces, `coseno( X )` tendrá **mas precisión** que `seno( X - ( PI / 2 ) )`, por el sencillo motivo de que lo segundo **usa 2 números imprecisos** pare realizar el cálculo, lo cual **aumentará** la **imprecisión** de la salida.

¡ Que cosas !

Answer (score 6):

Simple: Circulo Trigonometrico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asumiendo que tu reloj tendrá radio 1 en el plano de coordenadas cartesiano  entonces puedes usar la siguiente función:

```
function cordenadas(minutos){
   var radianes = (2 * Math.PI)/ 60 * minutos;
   var x = Math.cos(radianes);
   var y = Math.sin(radianes);
   return [x, y];
}
```

si el radio de tu reloj fuese mayor, simplemente multiplicas el resultado por el radio.

La idea esta basada en el circulo trigonométrico, sabemos que una circunferencia siempre tendrá dos pi radianes.

Obviamente debemos de establecer una relación entre los minutos y el circulo trigonometrico, por defecto esta en pi radianes entonces debemos de convertir los minutos a radianes.

Si gustas usar en otro sistema de coordenadas, simplemente se hace una transformación.