# Precisión de atof (o alternativas)

Tags: c, conversión-de-tipos

Necesitaría saber si hay alguna forma de mejor (o especificar) la precisión de la función `atof`. Por supuesto mi objetivo es pasar un `string` a `float`. Actualmente lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
char buffer[]={"3435.68209"};
float resultado;

resultado = atof(buffer);
```

Pero el valor final luego de la conversión me da: 3435.68213

Entiendo perfectamente el por que de ese "error" y el funcionamiento de los `float`, pero el sistema que estoy realizando tiene que ser muy preciso y esa diferencia no es aceptable.

¿Hay alguna manera de especificar o mejorar la precisión de `atof`?

¿Hay alguna otra función para reemplazarlo?

¿Conocen algun otro metodo para pasar de `string` a `float` con un 100% de precisión que no sea utilizando una función?

**Edito para agregar mas info:**

En mi aplicación el valor original en el string siempre va a tener como maximo 5 digitos antes del punto decimal y 6 digitos luego del punto decimal.

Es decir: XXXXX.YYYYYY (puede tener menos en ambos casos, pero jamás mas)

Comment: Échale un vistazo a [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29626/asignar-a-un-float-un-literal-de-punto-flotante-sin-sufijo/29651#29651).

Comment: Gracias, muy interesante la explicación

Comment: Hay librerías especializadas en número con **precisión arbitraria**. Consulta sobre libmpfi ( http://mpfi.gforge.inria.rf )

Comment: Ah, se me olvidaba. Dependiendo de para que lo quieras, puedes usar número en **punto fijo**, pero no podrás usar la mayoría de las funciones de la biblioteca estandar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atof` es una función que te devuelve un tipo `double`. `double` es un tipo con una precisión superior a `float`, de hecho lo normal es que dedique el doble de bits a almacenar el número (4 bytes para `float` y 8 para `double`).

El problema de los números en coma flotante es que tienen una precisión determinada. En el caso de `float` suele rondar los 6 dígitos y en el caso de `double`, 15. De hecho esta información está disponible en `float.h`:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Digitos float: %d\n",FLT_DIG);
  printf("Digitos double: %d\n",DBL_DIG);
}
```

En mi caso este código arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
Digitos float: 6
Digitos double: 15
```

Si quieres una precisión superior a la ofertada por `FLT_DIG` te recomiendo pasarte al tipo `double`.

Tu código corregido:

```
char buffer[]={"3435.68209"};
double resultado = atof(buffer);
```

Comment: Gracias! Efectivamente fue una distracción mía almacenar el resultado de la conversión en un float y no en un double. Adicionalmente, mientras investigaba encontré la función strtod que convierte string a double. Es totalmente equivalente a atof con la diferencia que atof tiene comportamiento indefinido cuando no es posible convertir el valor y strtod contempla el caso de error. Solo comento esto para que pueda servirle a alguien mas en el futuro, pero tu respuesta es perfectamente valida. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Tan solo como referencia (ya que la [respuesta de eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34157/2742) es válida) puedes configurar el comportamiento de los números en coma flotante mediante la función [`fesetround`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround). Podría serte útil.

#### `fesetround`

Configura la dirección en que se redondea el número en coma flotante al realizar operaciones. Dado que pasar de texto a número es una operación con coma flotante, los diferentes parámetros usados variarán el resultado. Se puede configurar con las siguientes opciones:

- `FE_DOWNWARD`: Redondeo a la baja (hacia -∞).
- `FE_TONEAREST`: Redondeo hacia el entero más cercano.
- `FE_TOWARDZERO`: Redondeo hacia cero.
- `FE_UPWARD`: Redondeo al alza (hacia +∞).

#### Pobando las diferentes configuraciones:

Usando `atof` de tu número de ejmplo con las diferentes configuraciones obtenemos:

`FE_DOWNWARD`

- Original: `3435.68209`
- Resultado: `3435.68213`

`FE_TONEAREST`

- Original: `3435.68209`
- Resultado: `3435.68188`

`FE_TOWARDZERO`

- Original: `3435.68209`
- Resultado: `3435.68213`

`FE_UPWARD`

- Original: `3435.68209`
- Resultado: `3435.68188`

---

Los mejores resultados los obtienes con `FE_TOWARDZERO` y `FE_DOWNWARD` que dan un error de `0,00004`; pero esto podría cambiar con diferentes números.

Comment: un buen aporte siempre es de agradecer