# ¿Cómo se comparan doubles en C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Si tenemos dos valores tales como a = 0.999999... y b = 1.0, es decir que son representaciones decimales del mismo número real 1, no obstante la expresión 
x == y será evaluada como false... el siguiente código funciona, pero si uso un bucle para imprimir por pantalla la altura del objeto en función del tiempo t entonces la altura h acaba siendo ligeramente negativa en lugar de devolverme cero...

```
//
// describir la trayectoria de un objeto que cae desde una  
// altura de 100 metros hasta que se detiene en el suelo
//

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

constexpr double altura_sub0{ 100.0 };
constexpr double g{ 9.81 };

int main()
{
    double t_iter{ 0.0 };
    double t{ sqrt(altura_sub0 / (g / 2)) };
    double h{ altura_sub0 };
    h = altura_sub0 - g*t*t / 2;
    if (h == 0.0)
        std::cout << "resultado correcto de h = 0 en tiempo "
        << t << " segundos." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "fallo!, tras " << t << " segundos el objeto"
        "se encuentra en h = " << h << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Relacionada: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%C3%A9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%C3%A1lculos-aritm%C3%A9ticos-correctamente

Comment: [Esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29626/asignar-a-un-float-un-literal-de-punto-flotante-sin-sufijo/29651) puede ayudarte también.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En general comparar dos variables `double` no se hace con `==`, debido a la representación interna de esos valores reales (mantisa, exponente).

Lo más común es evaluar si la diferencia entre esos dos valores es menor que un `EPSILON` que previamente se define (de acuerdo a la precisión que se requiera), y si la diferencia es menor se dice que los números son iguales.

**Función tipo**

```
bool isEqual(double d1, double d2, double epsilon = 0.00000000001)
{
    return fabs(d1 - d2) < epsilon;
}
```

**Ejemplo**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>


bool isEqual(double d1, double d2, double epsilon = 0.000000001)
{
    return fabs(d1 - d2) < epsilon;
}

int main()
{
    double primero=.33333;
    double segundo=1.0/3.0;

    printf ("primero: %.20f\n", primero);
    printf ("segundo: %.20f\n", segundo);

    std::cout << "isEqual: " << (isEqual(primero, segundo)) << "\n"; //Epsilon por defecto
    std::cout << "isEqual: " << (isEqual(primero, segundo, 0.0001)) << "\n"; 

 }
```

**Resultado**

```
primero: 0.33333000000000001517
segundo: 0.33333333333333331483
isEqual: 0
isEqual: 1
```

Comment: Los números en coma flotante no se deben comparar entre sí usando el operador de comparación porque su representación no es exacta y está sujeta a a decimales no significativos que pueden "bailar" y hacer que la comparación falle. Por mucho que tengan mantisa y exponente su representación está normalizada, luego el mismo número se representará exactamente igual en dos variables diferentes... el problema es cuando realizamos operaciones sobre dicho valor. Dicho de otra forma: esto puede fallar: `(1e10+1.0-1.0==1e10)` mientras que esto no fallará `1e10==1e10`

Answer (score 4):

Debes evitar comparar números en coma flotante mediante la igualdad, cada uno de los números puede tener precisiones distintas según su tipo o su valor puede no ser exáctamente representable de manera binaria causando errores de redondeo.

Por este motivo debes compararlos por la *casi igualdad*, una función así te podría ser de ayuda:

```
#include <cstdint> 

bool casi_iguales(float izquierda, float derecha)
{
     return fabs(izquierda – derecha) <= FLT_EPSILON;
}

bool casi_iguales(double izquierda, double derecha)
{
     return fabs(izquierda – derecha) <= DBL_EPSILON;
}
```

Los valores `FLT_EPSILON` y `DBL_EPSILON` pertenecen a la cabecera [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) y son la diferencia entre el valor 1 y el siguiente valor representable por `float` y `double` respectivamente; en otras palabras, son aproximadamente el menor valor representable por cada uno de los tipos, así que si la diferencia entre `izquierda` y `derecha` es menor o igual a este valor es que ambos valores son *casi iguales*.