# Mi código no imprime una parte en pantalla

Tags: c

Tengo un problema con un código para un examen. El programa debe extraer un conjunto de valores tipo flotantes de un archivo, y encontrar los pares de valores más cercanos; sin embargo, al momento de imprimir en pantalla los resultados, cuando hay varios pares con la misma distancia, no imprime nada.
¿Cómo puedo corregirlo?

Espero poder lograr que imprima todos los pares con la misma distancia entre ellos (la mínima)

Este es el código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    char file_name[100];
    int n, i;
   
    printf("\tEscriba el nombre del archivo:\n");
    scanf("%s", file_name);

    FILE *archivo = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (archivo == NULL) {
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //sacar el valor de n contandoi los elemntos 
    float value;
    n = 0;
    while (fscanf(archivo, "%f\n", &value) != EOF) {
        n++;
    }

    rewind(archivo);  //inciio

    float a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fscanf(archivo, "%f\n", &a[i]);
    }

    
    fclose(archivo); //cerrar owo

    //algoritmo de selección para el orden :3
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int maxIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j] > a[maxIndex]) {
                maxIndex = j;
            }
        }
       
        float temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[maxIndex];
        a[maxIndex] = temp;
    }

    //valores ordenados
    printf("\nValores ordenados de mayor a menor:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%.2f, ", a[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    int distanceSize = n - 1;

    float distancia[distanceSize];

    // Calcular la distancia directa lineal
    printf("\nDistancia: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < distanceSize; i++) {
        distancia[i] = a[i] - a[i + 1];
        printf("%.2f, ", distancia[i]);
    }

    //ordenar de menor a mayor los valores de la distancia 
    for (i = 0; i < distanceSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < distanceSize - i - 1; j++) {
            if (distancia[j] > distancia[j + 1]) {
                float temp = distancia[j];
                distancia[j] = distancia[j + 1];
                distancia[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }  //burbuja pq nu me salió el otro aquí


    // Imprimir los valores ordenados
    printf("\n\nValores ordenados de la distancia:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < distanceSize; i++) {
        printf("%.2f, ", distancia[i]);
    }


    float min = distancia[0];
  
    // printf("\n%.2f\n", distancia[0]);
    printf("\n\nDistancia Min: %.2f\n", min);
  
    printf("\nPARES CERCANOS\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i + 1] - a[i] == min) {
            printf("(%.2f, %.2f)", a[i], a[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Desconozco si existe un problema con la memoria o requiera de un tipo de estructura más compleja.

Esto es lo que pone al compilar:

Comment: Has puesto que añadias el error al compilar, pero no la has añadido, quiza pueda ayudar a encontrar el error a quien pueda/sepa ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código tiene los siguientes problemas:

- Uso de ["*Arreglos de Tamaño Variable*"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vla+%5Bc%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D) (VLA o "*Variable Lenght Array*" en inglés) con las variables `float a[n];` y `float distancia[distanceSize];`, que deberías evitar.
- Repetición de código: repites los algoritmos de ordenación innecesariamente.
- [Comparación por igualdad de números en compa flotante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/40643/2742), cosa que también debes evitar.

Si arreglas estos problemas tu código funciona como esperas y podría parecerse a esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int casi_iguales(float izquierda, float derecha)
{
    return fabs(izquierda - derecha) <= __FLT_EPSILON__;
}

void selection_sort(float *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int maxIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j] > a[maxIndex]) {
                maxIndex = j;
            }
        }
       
            float temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[maxIndex];
            a[maxIndex] = temp;
    }
}

void imprime(float *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%.10f, ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    char file_name[100] = "";
    printf("\tEscriba el nombre del archivo:\n");
    scanf("%s", file_name);

    FILE *archivo = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (archivo == NULL) {
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo %s.\n", file_name);
        return 1;
    }

    float value;
    int n = 0;
    while (fscanf(archivo, "%f\n", &value) != EOF) {
        n++;
    }

    rewind(archivo);
    // No usamos VLA.
    float *a = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fscanf(archivo, "%f\n", &a[i]);
    }
    fclose(archivo);

    selection_sort(a, n);
    printf("\nValores ordenados de mayor a menor:\n");
    imprime(a, n);

    int distanceSize = n - 1;
    float *distancia = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * distanceSize);
    printf("\nDistancia: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < distanceSize; i++) {
        distancia[i] = a[i] - a[i + 1];
    }
    imprime(distancia, distanceSize);

    selection_sort(distancia, distanceSize);
    printf("\n\nValores ordenados de la distancia:\n");
    imprime(distancia, distanceSize);

    float min = distancia[distanceSize - 1];
    printf("\n\nDistancia Min: %.10f\n\nPARES CERCANOS\n", min);
  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (casi_iguales(a[i] - a[i + 1], min)) {
            printf("(%.10f, %.10f)", a[i], a[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    free(a);
    free(distancia);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVbvT9s8EP6c/BW3vuJVQktKgf14KUxCvEVC6mAa274wFLmOQ40SmzkpsE3929nZsd2kY2OVKtt357vnnjtfS7euKX18/IcLWiwyBgdVnXGZzN@GHVHBZ@syxcV1V1aSev7LTS5qLQvvJM@AKkZUmpFaVlEc/giDk9PpBDZzOIRc3jIR9YwuqR/q3gB69714HAb5LYaq8yhHySgZfRG9MAj0rr3t7FeHnd29l6/saSfRh9dv7HE3Maf/nPFe0hx3dq3gpRfsWcmrxJ5RgSIDjhayYlGO@2UYIk6gpOIpv16QglVRXkhSA//@dcGZysgAGkHGFKNzYihQrF4oATmZVZE3hC1vAweHkKYn04/p5P3F6fT8LE1NLENoxQpGay5FWklV23CbGEcjEcZ/LhVE@siR5e0xLgcg0P8It/1@DGgSaHVJHk5Fxh7QimNiq3s3WgJ9feFG38XF3Qt4DhG5vLmCt0AunYcrqwxaLm@0y2AZ6i80nzCwG0tKzcpbtCSX/GrsbCDQRyP13seriy0p2mgHqFx6dniJrVOyv6elRYltut5GMtrWnTcwwGLj3yubJrCFLwkXTVdj2RTkvGCpICW7HG1va3i9HqaFyvYb0Im23NWTiio@I8AKELKcKYZtUABRdM7v5L7tuYoSoZFVCMpHQYV7TtbcPypvg2ko48GUzVkdwtmn6bSb9ZnE1oLbRSaBzBRXsEIBG1WCQLqhA9fGI0NQGAyHUBFKzMU7UiDZOA8EUClqItArvhpUsVIgDchAUyE0XDANT1fJlCUM7ucYBqK8SdpiwEQ2cgPiX3MnhheHMDk/aZIQ/b5Fodg9F5m7FY8BhkMcTpzL0MXcJBjIdUhckqKQNKr4dybzRhrDJrbM@PmO@S3EVeP4ebFCNBxSphQSJe81qLUHjS0rTGWRT0Mjq0CqjAmSyardh5/XlZrvknxDzARKJqRy3eMehXetU8p4hXWh7AITx@ya@eApslr@N1S1PTnkx6SgiwJzLAisfGUcB1xNoOCCkaKdzP/OZh/cmH2C@3akVhl8ADc4cNnSix5hV837dRx428GTuBsylWlWxz7S2snil5I94/PUhOZdp0@W9DdFbUdfr@mfYjd1K7l@WCuOOoXfMgR1JpJoVQPecbEPZiCaxkZf6wNMvD/6MLmA48mH46Oz84sG3vNPR8@jzu/mWtWaWPZnxQWL7Gg2S2wH9MDfMVNpaV@dYtjwppH0zqdvwNnJhcNm@fjo/3@EPwE)</kbd>.