# Mi codigo deja de sumar convirtiendo de hexadecimal a decimal

Tags: c++, string, float

Quiero convertir un string de 6 bytes en hexadecimal a un float

```
   float desencapsularArchivo::hex2dec(string aConvertir)
    {
    int cantHex = aConvertir.size();

    float decimal = 0;

    for(int hexNum = 0;hexNum < cantHex; hexNum++)
    {
        char piv = aConvertir.at(hexNum);

        float hex;

        switch(piv)
        {
        case 'A': case 'a':
            hex = 10;
            break;
        case 'B': case 'b':
            hex = 11;
            break;
        case 'C': case 'c':
            hex = 12;
            break;
        case 'D': case 'd':
            hex = 13;
            break;
        case 'E': case 'e':
            hex = 14;
            break;
        case 'F': case 'f':
            hex = 15;
            break;
        default:
            hex = (int)piv - 48;
        }
        decimal = decimal + hex * pow(16, cantHex - hexNum - 1);
    }

    return decimal;

}
```

Si quiero introducir por ejemplo la cadena `00805f181015`
el resultado es:
`551351222272`
en vez de:
`551351226389`

Segun mis pruebas faltan sumas los ultimos 4 caracteres del hexadecimal, pero no se por que no lo hace.

Cabe mencionar que para imprimir uso `cout << "Decimal: " << setprecision(0) << fixed << decimal;`

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente

Comment: ¿Por qué `float` en lugar de `uint64_t`*? Digo, es un hexstring lo que tienes ...

Comment: Intente utilizar uint64_t y no me funcionaba o no supe implementarlo, me seguia marcanod numeros negatimos como un int de 32 y ocupo que sea hasta un minimo de 48 bits, por eso uso float

Comment: Entonces usa `unsigned long long` o `uint64_t`. `float` es igual de 32 bits.

Comment: Si quieres convertir un string de 6 bytes en un número necesitarás uno que admita 6 bytes... `uint64_t` ocupa 8 luego debería ser más que suficiente... otra cosa es que el algoritmo te falle por otra razón

Answer (score 3):

Tu algoritmo es correcto; los tipos usados son incorrectos. Estás teniendo un problema de pérdida de precisión al usar números en coma flotante. Como ya se mencionó en [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29626/asignar-a-un-float-un-literal-de-punto-flotante-sin-sufijo/29651#29651), no todos los números decimales son representables con el [formato de coma flotante IEEE](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante).

En concreto el número `551351226389` no tiene representación precisa en coma flotante, así que el valor que se aproxima es `551351222272`<sup>1</sup>, puedes comprobarlo [en esta página web](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/). Si cambias todos tus `float` de tu código por tipos enteros ([`long` o `long long`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)), el error desaparece.

---

1. Una pérdida de precisión del 0,000001%.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres convertir un string de 6 bytes en un número necesitarás uno que admita 6 bytes... `uint64_t` ocupa 8 luego debería ser más que suficiente... otra cosa es que el algoritmo te falle por otra razón .

Y para muestra, un botón. El siguiente ejemplo convierte perfectamente, entre otros, el número problemático (`00805f181015`):

```
unsigned long long Convertir(std::string const& cadena)
{
  unsigned long long numero = 0;

  for( char c : cadena )
  {
    numero *= 16;

    if( c >= 'a' )
      numero += c - 'a' + 10;
    else
      numero += c - '0';
  }

  return numero;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << Convertir("1") << '\n'
            << Convertir("10b") << '\n'
            << Convertir("123456") << '\n'
            << Convertir("999998") << '\n'
            << Convertir("00805f181015") << '\n';
}
```

PD.: Uso unsigned long long por no cargar librerías adicionales, pero el efecto es el mismo que al usar `uint64_t`