# ¿Cómo definir la precisión de un double en C ++?

Tags: c++

No logro definir la precisión de un `double` en C++. Por ejemplo, si el input es `14049.30493` entonces espero como ouput 14049.304930000.

Con mi código :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double d;
    scanf("%lf", &d);
    printf("%lf", d);
    return 0;
}
```

obtengo el valor `14049.304930`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedes definir la precisión de un `double`, su precisión viene dada por cómo esté implementado. C++ sigue la implementación [IEEE-754](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante) que dispone de diferentes formatos; el formato de número de coma flotante que se use dependerá de la arquitectura de la máquina en que se ejecute tu programa. Los tipos de datos de coma flotante de C++ son:

- `float`: Precisión simple. Habitualmente son un tipo de 32 bits de ancho que sigue el [IEEE-754](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante) de 32 bits.
- `double` - Precisión doble. Habitualmente son un tipo de 64 bits de ancho que sigue el [IEEE-754](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante) de 64 bits.
- `long double` - Precisión extendida. Habitualmente son un tipo de 80 bits en arquitecturas de 32 y 64 bits. No necesariamente sigue el [IEEE-754](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante).

---

No quieres cambiar la precisión de `double` (porque eso no se puede cambiar), quieres cambiar los decimales que muestra por pantalla un valor de ese tipo. Para eso necesitarás la cabecera [`<iomanip>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) que ofrece una utilidad para manipular la precisión que se usará para mostrar números por pantalla: el modificador [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision):

```
double d = 1.0000001;
std::cout << d << '\n';
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> 1
> ```

Porque la precisión que se usa por defecto para mostrar datos no considera relevante el `0.0000001`, pero si indicamos una precisión de 8 dígitos:

```
double d = 1.0000001;
std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << d << '\n';
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> 1.0000001
> ```

Hay que tener en cuenta que esta precisión usa también la parte entera del número, este código:

```
double d = 1111111.0000001;
std::cout << std::setprecision(8) << d << '\n';
```

Muestra:

> ```
> 1111111
> ```

Si queremos usar la máxima precisión posible para mostrar un dato determinado, podemos apoyarnos en la cabecera [`<limits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits) que ofrece una utilidad para saber cuál es la máxima cantidad de dígitos que un tipo de datos puede mostrar en base 10: la función [`std::numeric_limits::digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10).

Por lo tanto este código:

```
double d = 1111111.0000001;
std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1) << d << '\n';
```

Muestra:

> ```
> 1111111.0000001
> ```

Pero si tu número no tiene valores significativos después de un dígito determinado, no te los mostrará, para ello necesitas el modificador [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw), que te permite indicar cuál será el ancho al mostrar datos, deberás combinarlo con [std::left](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) (para indicar que el dato estará a la izquierda del relleno) y [`std::setfill('0')`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) para indicar que quieres rellenar con el caracter `0`. Así que si éste es tu código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    constexpr auto precision = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1;
    double d;
    std::cin >> d;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(precision)
              << std::setw(precision)
              << std::setfill('0')
              << std::left
              << d << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Si introduces `14049.30493` verás por pantalla:

> ```
> 14049.3049300000
> ```

Pero como puedes ver, es muy complicado y poco práctico, es más sencillo usar [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) de la cabecera [`<ios>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ios), si tienes este código:

```
double d = 14049.30493;
std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1)
          << std::fixed
          << d << '\n';
```

Se mostrará (posiblemente):

> ```
> 14049.3049300000002404
> ```

Para saber por qué el programa se está inventando decimales [lee este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/29651/2742).

Comment: Qué horror. Gracias por la respuesta !

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double a = 14049.30493;
  double  intpart;
  double fractpart = modf (a, &intpart);
  fractpart  = roundf(fractpart * 100000.0)/100000.0; 
  double b = intpart + fractpart;
  printf("%.9lf", b);
}
```

Salida: 14049.304930000

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Y sabe como definir la precisión cuando tengo dos figuras, una en el otro y el otro doble, siempre con tanta precisión en el doble?

Comment: @Marine1 no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Recuerda no formular preguntas en los comentarios, crea otra nueva pregunta explicando esa nueva duda y no dudaremos en ayudarte. Buen día

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de Paula no pasa todo el caso de prueba. Intenté esto gracias al [comentario de quetonix](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-basic-data-types/forum) :

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::fixed;

int main() {
    // Complete the code.
    int a; long b; char c; float d; double e;
    cin>>e;
    cout.precision(9);
    cout<<fixed<<e<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

No sé para usted pero a mi me parece mas simple

Answer (score -1):

**Utiliza** la libreria **iomanip** para fijar la precisión en el formato de salida, **en combinación con setfixed**.

Este ejemplo es sacado de la documentación de la libreria ([aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)):

```
// setprecision example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::fixed
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

int main () {
  double f =3.14159;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::fixed;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

La salida es:

```
3.1416
3.14159
3.14159
3.141590000
```

Espero que te sirva,
Saludos.

Comment: He dicho que lo he sacado de la documentación de la libreria. Tal y como dices, no he puesto la fuente. Edito. Gracias

Comment: Pero queda mejor si pones el enlace... porque webs de documentación hay unas cuantas...