# Problemas al restar con decimales en javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer una resta con javascript, pero tengo problemas al restar con 
números decimales por ejemplo:

Flotacion: function(){
                    var Uno = parseFloat(1);
                    var Dos = parseFloat(0.65);
                    var RR = (Uno - Dos);
                    $('#txtResultadoFlotacion').val(RR);
                }

RESTA CORRECTA

y debugeando obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en RR tiene un valor de 0.35 el cual es correcto.

RESTA INCORRECTA:

Pero si quiero hacer una resta con valor decimal entre el rango de 0.65 a 0.99 me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a lo que yo esperaría es que RR=0.30
AYUDA, por favor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript opera con números en coma flotante, los cuales **no siempre pueden almacenar el valor exacto de un número**.
Este es un problema común en muchos lenguajes, no solo *javascript*

Te recomiendo visitar
[¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%C3%A9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%C3%A1lculos-aritm%C3%A9ticos-correctamente)
donde se habla en profundidad sobre el tema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucho