# Redondear dos decimales javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema al intentar redondear un numero, pero quisiera redondear sus dos decimales
por ejemplo un numero como 16.2453
redondearlo a 16.25?
he buscado por internet pero lo unico que encuentro son maneras de redondearlo a entero, en este caso a 17,
estoy utilizando JavaScript

Comment: ¿Y ya probaste con `toFixed(cantidad)`?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Redondear a dos decimales cuando sea necesario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48958/redondear-a-dos-decimales-cuando-sea-necesario)

Comment: Como dice BetaM, usa `numero.toFixed(digitos)` para redondear el número a la cantidad de dígitos deseados. Usar `toFixed()` sin argumentos redondeara al número entero mas cercano.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414023/pierdo-un-cero-al-redondear-un-float-con-precision-de-2-en-java/414232#414232 entra aqui la respuesta es en Java, lo que debes hacer es llevarla a tu lenguaje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reutiliza la siguiente funcion:

```js
function round(value, decimals) {
  return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
}

function redondeaTexto()
{
 var valorTexto= document.getElementById('miNumero').value;
 
  document.getElementById('miNumero').value= round(valorTexto,2);
 
}
```

```html
<input id="miNumero" value='1.0567'></input>
<button type="button" onClick='redondeaTexto()'>Redondea</button>
```