# Division entre valores double da como resultado 0

Tags: java

estoy escribiendo un código en Java consistente en diversas operaciones matemáticas sencillas (divisiones y multiplicaciones). Se trata de un problema de Física.

Resulta que a la hora de calcular ciertas operaciones, con valores ya obtenidos, el resultados de éstas da 0. No entiendo por qué ocurre este error, pues se trata de operaciones sencillas.

```
public Calculos(int alfa, double Vo) {
        mE = 9.11 * (Math.pow(10, -31));
        q = 6.67 * (Math.pow(10, -19));
        E = 3.5 * (Math.pow(10, 3));

        a = 0;
        Vox = 0;
        Voy = 0;
        t = 0;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        tTotal = 0;

        this.alfa = alfa;
        this.Vo = Vo;
    }

    public void mostrarDatos() {
            System.out.println("Angulo de lanzamiento: " + alfa + "º");
            System.out.println("Velocidad inicial: " + Vo + " m/s");
            System.out.println("Vox = " + Vo + "·cos " + alfa + " = " + String.format("%.2f", Vo * (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(alfa)))));
            System.out.println("Voy = " + Vo + "·sen " + alfa + " = " + String.format("%.2f", Vo * (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(alfa)))));
            Vox = Vo * (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(alfa)));
            Voy = Vo * (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(alfa)));
        }

        public void calcularAceleracion() {
            System.out.println("Aceleracion");
            System.out.println("a = F/mE = q·E/mE = " + String.format("%.2f", (q * E) / mE));
            a = (q * E) / mE;
        }

        public void calcularAlturaMaxima() {
            System.out.println("Despejando, tiempo en alcanzar y maxima = " + String.format("%.2f", (Voy / a)) + " s");
            t = Voy / a;
            System.out.println("Por tanto la altura maxima y = " + String.format("%.2f", (Voy * t - 0.5 * a * (Math.pow(t, 2)))) + " m");
            y = (Voy * t - 0.5 * a * (Math.pow(t, 2)));
            System.out.println("La coordenada x de la altura maxima x = Vox·t = " + Vox + "·" + t + " = " + String.format("%.2f", Vox * t) + " m");

        }
```

La ejecución es la siguiente:

```
Angulo de lanzamiento: 45º
Velocidad inicial: 5000000.0 m/s
Vox = 5000000.0·cos 45 = 3535533,91
Voy = 5000000.0·sen 45 = 3535533,91
Aceleracion
a = F/mE = q·E/mE = 2562568605927552,00
Despejando, tiempo en alcanzar y maxima = 0,00 s
Por tanto la altura maxima y = 0,00 m
La coordenada x de la altura maxima x = Vox·t = 3535533.905932738·1.3796836103254332E-9 = 0,00 m
```

Todos los datos son de tipo double excepto el valor alfa, que es int.

Comment: la variable `a` tiene valor 0

Comment: @x-rw la `a` podria ser 0 si no ejecuta `calcularAceleracion()` , pero no creo que sea su caso, el valor de `a` lo saca de `a = (q * E) / mE;`.Saludos

Comment: Hace poco leí esto, y es muy interesante: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qué-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-cálculos-aritméticos-correctamente Saludos.

Comment: Qué son `a`, `Vox`, `Voy`. Me refiero a: ¿qué tipos de variables son? ¿Son `double` o son `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que usted necesite mas capacidad a la hora de mostrar los decimales por ejemplo puede mirar esto:

- String.format("%.50f"

---

```
public void calcularAlturaMaxima() {

//..

System.out.println("Despejando, tiempo en alcanzar y maxima = " + String.format("%.50f", (Voy / a)) + " s");

//..

System.out.println("Por tanto la altura maxima y = " + String.format("%.50f", (Voy * t - 0.5 * a * (Math.pow(t, 2)))) + " m");

//..
```

yo he calculado con 1, 1, para `alfa` y `Vo` y el resultado es este:

```
Angulo de lanzamiento: 1º
Velocidad inicial: 1.0 m/s
Vox = 1.0·cos 1 = 1.00
Voy = 1.0·sen 1 = 0.02
Aceleracion
a = F/mE = q·E/mE = 2562568605927552.00
Despejando, tiempo en alcanzar y maxima = 0.00000000000000000681051285687097000000000000000000 s
Por tanto la altura maxima y = 0.00000000000000000005942991921222852000000000000000 m
La coordenada x de la altura maxima x = Vox·t = 0.9998476951563913·6.81051285687097E-18 = 0.00 m
```

---

El cual es:

```
Angulo de lanzamiento: 1º
Velocidad inicial: 1.0 m/s
Vox = 1.0·cos 1 = 1.00
Voy = 1.0·sen 1 = 0.02
Aceleracion
a = F/mE = q·E/mE = 2562568605927552.00
Despejando, tiempo en alcanzar y maxima = 0.00 s
Por tanto la altura maxima y = 0.00 m
La coordenada x de la altura maxima x = Vox·t = 0.9998476951563913·6.81051285687097E-18 = 0.00 m
```

para:

- String.format("%.2f"

---

```
public void calcularAlturaMaxima() {

//..

System.out.println("Despejando, tiempo en alcanzar y maxima = " + String.format("%.2f", (Voy / a)) + " s");

//..

System.out.println("Por tanto la altura maxima y = " + String.format("%.2f", (Voy * t - 0.5 * a * (Math.pow(t, 2)))) + " m");

//..
```

---

Entoces en este ejemplo (y seguramente en muchos) realmente no es que de, un resultado de cero, simplemente es que para la precision que usted determina en `format...%.2f`, solo se muestran esos (0,00 s y 0,00 m).