# Al ejecutar un proyecto de Netbeans en Maven en un pc funciona printea bien y en otro no

Tags: java, netbeans, arduino

He cargado un proyecto de Netbeans en Maven en un pc con Windows 8.1.

Al ejecutarlo, sale la interfaz gráfica de forma correcta, los botones funcionan correctamente pero el `JLabelResult` en un pc se actualiza correctamente y en otro no.

La línea recibe información por Serial desde un arduino.

Sí la información que recibe es `println("texto");` funciona, pero si tiene que mostrar un `println(float);` en un pc sale correctamente pero en el otro en uno de los loops aparece, en otro aparece con mal formato, en otro no aparece.

¿Alguna idea de si hay alguna opción que viene configurada por defecto en Windows 10?

En la primera foto debería aparecer *Ciclos realizados*:
[image: PC con Windows 8.1 conectado a arduino]

Pero no aparece mientras que en la segunda *(PC con Windows 10)* si aparece:
[image: PC con Windows 10 conectado a arduino]

Lectura del serial.

```
  public Window() {
      initComponents();

      try {
          ino.arduinoRXTX("COM3", 9600, listener);
      } catch (ArduinoException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  }

    }
```

Lectura del float:

```
    SerialPortEventListener listener = new SerialPortEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent spe) {
        try {
            if (ino.isMessageAvailable()) {
                //System.out.println(ino.printMessage());
                jLabelResult.setText(ino.printMessage());

            }
        } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ArduinoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }        
};
```

Comment: No comprendo bien el problema. ¿Puedes indicar en qué línea de código es que se ve el problema mencionado? De momento, cuando leo que tienes un `println(float)` ya se me ocurre que puedes estar pasando por [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/227)

Comment: Sí, me refiero a que en Windows 10 al ejecutar en netbeans el proyecto todo va perfectamente, la comunicación cor arduino es correcta y va mostrando los diferentes mensajes que recibe por el monitor serial.
Cuando tiene que mostrar el total de ciclos muestra " Ciclos realizados" y a continuación el valor de un float, en el caso de la imagen el valor es 1.
Si ejecuto el mismo proyecto en un pc con windows 8.1 el float no aparece o aparece con mal formato, como se ve en la primera imagen que no aparece la línea Ciclos realizados + el float.

Comment: Quita las fotos y pega el código en cuestión para que sea posible ayudarte.

Comment: El código es exactamente el mismo, se utiliza incluso la misma placa de arduino con el mismo código en ella. El archivo es exactamente el mismo, pero en Win10 funciona correctamente y en Win8.1 No muestra bien los datos que contienen un float.