# Precisión arbitrariamente grande de enteros y float (en C)

Tags: c

Mi pregunta es: ¿hay alguna forma de modificar un tipo de dato (float o entero) para que tenga una precisión arbitrariamente grande (por ejemplo solo limitada por la capacidad física de la memoria del ordenador, o algo así). Dedicarme a escribir "long" delante de cada tipo no parece funcionar (o al menos el operador sizeof devuelve la misma cantidad de bytes).

Comment: No la hay. La precisión de cada uno de los tipos fundamentales de [tag:c] viene dada por estándares ajenos al lenguaje. Si quieres precisiones arbitrarias [debes programarlas tú](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69855/elegir-cuantos-decimales-guardo-en-una-variable/70625#70625) o usar librerías externas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los números cuya precisión o cuyo rango esté sólo limitado por la capacidad física de la memoria del ordenador son conocidos como *bignum*, *bigint* o [números de precisión arbitraria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precisi%C3%B3n_arbitraria).

Hay pocos lenguajes que soporten precisión arbitraria de manera nativa, y C no es uno de ellos. Si necesitas este tipo de utilidad deberás confiar en librerías de terceros, como por ejemplo: [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/).