# ¿Cuál es el máximo valor almacenable en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

De acuerdo al los tipos de datos el entero es de 32 bits, y el rango es del `0` al `4.294.967.295`

En ese caso, ¿Cómo es que se almacena un número con rango superior al billón? Ejemplo: `159.543.234.423.342`.

Comment: manejar una cantidad muy grande como esa, pocas veces es necesaria, que uso le quieres dar?, las preguntas como estas no son bien recibidad en SO, trata de plantear tu problema, o de lo contrario tu pregunta puede ser borrada.

Comment: También es posible implementar un sistema (no es fácil de programar) en el que se pueda sumar un número mediante una cadena de caracteres, de modo que el único límite sería la memoria del sistema o lo que permita el intérprete Javascript almacenar.

Comment: gracias @Luis por tu respuesta y por el tip, lo tendré en cuenta, es con fines didacticos ya que la teoría te dice una cosa pero en la práctica muchas veces es complicado representar un caso así. Un caso seria crear una calculadora que traduzca numeros binarios

Comment: gracias @ArtEze ese seria un caso tambien, algo similar nos habiamos planteado con uso de array donde cada elemento podria ser un digito del entero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber el numero maximo seguro escribe el comando:

```
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)  //9007199254740991
```

Leyendo un poco mas puedes modificar este valor aqui un ejemplo ten cuidado con esto valido para **ECMAScript 6**

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = Math.pow(2, 53)-1;
Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER = -Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
```

Pero debes tener cuidado al cambiar el valor ya que afecta [los calculos exactos en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente)

> [para saber mas puedes ver esta pregunta en
> ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Comment: exacto @JackNavaRow y la duda es de que pasa luego de ese limite, entiendo de que se debe cambiar de tipo de dato para seguir con la posibilidad de incrementar el valor, verdad?

Comment: cierto! le da un valor factorial pero no es muy exacto; tengo varias soluciones, la pregunta es para que lo quieres usar asi te podremos ayudar, propongo cerrar esta pregunta y hacer esta nueva pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Tu etiqueta es de *Javascript*, y en este lenguaje no defines el tipo de variable. Es decir, al ser un lenguaje débilmente tipado las variables se inicializan así:

```
var número=4;
var palabra="Hola mundo!";
```

Ahora bien, el número más grande que puedes representar en javascript es el +/- 9007199254740991.

> Cualquier número positivo y negativo que no supere 2^53 es representable.

Comment: gracias @Erlantz-calvo y una vez que sobrepasamos ese umbral como se maneja el dato?