# ¿Por qué no entra en el if con operaciones con decimales?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i += 0.1) {
    echo '<hr>' . $i . '</hr>';
    $suma = 0;
    $suma += $i;
    if ($i == 9.9)
        echo 'La suma total es: ' . $suma;
}

?>
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa, no se refleja el valor de la variable `$suma`.

¿Por qué ocurre este error y cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: Cual es el error? Podrias ser mas claro

Comment: No se observa ningun error [ejecutando el codigo](https://tio.run/##TYxBCsMgEEX3c4q/EGwIWLNMdZIL9BJSEhRalCRdlZ7dqu2is/jw/zxe8ilnlLNz8olojdtJBNZGBDvU7FmrocOLKrTcfIS0fpskFEQoIe25VtP@Yn8@HBj6v/ZcyO8Q1iIHM0Y1dj/b1aFhRzzcHct@QXPXzdCbaJ5y/gA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @IvanBotero, lee la pregunta y ejecuta el codigo que el provee. No se porque los puntos negativos a la pregunta, verdaderamente no muestra el valor que imprime por `echo`

Comment: Que no me muestra la variable $suma, es el error, supongo que fui claro

Comment: El problema esta en la condición del if.  Si pruebas a poner `if ($i > 9.9)` alli si imprime la suma.

Comment: Esta **casi** hay que cerrarla como **duplicada**, ¿ no ? [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/19610)

Comment: @Trauma comparto contigo respecto a la casi duplicidad. o sea el problema es ese.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian nunca compruebes números en coma flotante por equidad, los números en coma flotante son aproximaciones no valores exáctos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nunca me habia encontrado con este tipo de escenario e investigando di con esta [respuesta en stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148991/3590533) donde dice que cuando haces alguna computación con el tipo float con uno de los valores(en este caso el valor de la variable `$i`), **aunque parezcan idénticos internamente no lo son**. Por lo que **normalmente nunca comparas valores de coma flotante para igualdad, asi que necesitas usar una diferencia aceptable más pequeña**.(negrias son citas del post)

Adaptando esa respuesta a tu pregunta pude hacerlo funcionar de esta manera:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i+=0.1) 
{
    echo '<hr>' . $i . '</hr>';

    if(abs(($i-(9.9))/(9.9)) < 0.00001)
    {
        echo 'La suma total es: ' . $i;
    }

}
?>
```

Admito que tu pregunta me sorprendio mucho. Llegue a creer que era un error del lenguaje.

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema con el formato de alguna forma tienes que ponerlos igual.
Aquí otra forma de darle formato.
Un ejemplo :

```
<?php
$suma = 0;
for($i=  0;$i<10;$i= $i + 0.1) {

    $valor =  9.9;
    echo "$i == $valor <br>";
    $i = number_format($i,1,".",",");
        $valor = number_format($valor,1,".",",");
    if( $i == $valor) {
        echo 'La suma total es: papapapa...' ;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Porque siempre estás iniciando la variable en 0 en cada iteración, sacala del foreach

```
 <?php
$suma = 0;
for($i=0;$i<10;$i+=0.1) {
    echo '<hr>' . $i . '</hr>';
    $suma += $i;
    if($i == 9.9) echo 'La suma total es: ' . $suma;
}

?>
```

Comment: Pero aún asi deberia imprimirla, y tu código tampoco me la imprime

Comment: Segio, siquiera probaste el codigo?