# Duda while JAVA

Tags: java

Por qué si introduzco 4,95 me devuelve los 5 centimos y si introduzco 1,95 no me los devuelve?

```
package ejer30;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Expendedora {
    private double dinero;
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void setDinero() {
        dinero=sc.nextDouble();
    }

    public void calculaMonedas() {

        int cont2E=0;
        int cont1E=0;
        int cont50C=0;
        int cont20C=0;
        int cont10C=0;
        int cont5C=0;

        while (dinero>=2) {
            cont2E++;
            dinero=dinero-2;
        }

        while (dinero>=1) {
            cont1E++;
            dinero=dinero-1;
        }

        while (dinero>=0.50) {
            cont50C++;
            dinero=dinero-0.50;
        }

        while (dinero>=0.20) {
            cont20C++;
            dinero=dinero-0.20;
        }

        while (dinero>=0.10) {
            cont10C++;
            dinero=dinero-0.10;
        }

        while (dinero>=0.05) {
            cont5C++;
            dinero=dinero-0.05;
        }
            System.out.println("Monedas de 2€: "+cont2E);
            System.out.println("Monedas de 1€: "+cont1E);
            System.out.println("Monedas de 50 cent: "+cont50C);
            System.out.println("Monedas de 20 cent: "+cont20C);
            System.out.println("Monedas de 10 cent: "+cont10C);
            System.out.println("Monedas de 5 cent: "+cont5C);
    }       

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Expendedora a = new Expendedora();
        System.out.println("Introduce dinero: ");
        a.setDinero();
        a.calculaMonedas();
    }
}
```

Comment: hiciste un seguimiento de tu codigo?

Comment: Sí, he redactado mi duda ya que llevo 2h intentando encontrar el error

Comment: explica un pcoo tu codigo y el seguimiento que hiciste. en que punto de tu debug, el dinero cambia abruptamente?

Comment: Es lo que te comento al principo, no da fallo de compilación ni nada, es que a veces me devuelve los 5 centimos (0,05) y otras veces no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te puse en el enlace marcando esta pregunta como duplicado ([¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente)), el tipo `float` y `double` no son tipos precisos.  Aun cuando `dinero` tenga un valor de `0.05`, puede que internamente, el valor sea mas bien algo como `0.04999999...`, lo que haría que la condición `dinero>=0.05` devolviera `false`.

Para evitar estos problemas de precisión con valores monetarios, puedes usar el tipo `BigDecimal`. Aunque es mas incómodo en su uso, por lo menos es más preciso.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo tu código pudiera usar `BigDecimal`:

```
public class Expendedora {
    private static final BigDecimal DOS_EUROS = new BigDecimal("2.00");
    private static final BigDecimal UN_EURO = new BigDecimal("1.00");
    private static final BigDecimal CINCUENTA_CENTAVOS = new BigDecimal("0.50");
    private static final BigDecimal VEINTE_CENTAVOS = new BigDecimal("0.20");
    private static final BigDecimal DIEZ_CENTAVOS = new BigDecimal("0.10");
    private static final BigDecimal CINCO_CENTAVOS = new BigDecimal("0.05");

    private BigDecimal dinero;
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void setDinero() {
        dinero=sc.nextBigDecimal();
    }

    public void calculaMonedas() {
        int cont2E=0;
        int cont1E=0;
        int cont50C=0;
        int cont20C=0;
        int cont10C=0;
        int cont5C=0;

        while (dinero.compareTo(DOS_EUROS) >= 0) {
            cont2E++;
            dinero=dinero.subtract(DOS_EUROS);
        }

        while (dinero.compareTo(UN_EURO) >= 0) {
            cont1E++;
            dinero=dinero.subtract(UN_EURO);
        }

        while (dinero.compareTo(CINCUENTA_CENTAVOS) >= 0) {
            cont50C++;
            dinero=dinero.subtract(CINCUENTA_CENTAVOS);
        }

        while (dinero.compareTo(VEINTE_CENTAVOS) >= 0) {
            cont20C++;
            dinero=dinero.subtract(VEINTE_CENTAVOS);
        }

        while (dinero.compareTo(DIEZ_CENTAVOS) >= 0) {
            cont10C++;
            dinero=dinero.subtract(DIEZ_CENTAVOS);
        }

        while (dinero.compareTo(CINCO_CENTAVOS) >= 0) {
            cont5C++;
            dinero=dinero.subtract(CINCO_CENTAVOS);
        }

        System.out.println("Monedas de 2€: "+cont2E);
        System.out.println("Monedas de 1€: "+cont1E);
        System.out.println("Monedas de 50 cent: "+cont50C);
        System.out.println("Monedas de 20 cent: "+cont20C);
        System.out.println("Monedas de 10 cent: "+cont10C);
        System.out.println("Monedas de 5 cent: "+cont5C);
    }       

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Expendedora a = new Expendedora();
        System.out.println("Introduce dinero: ");
        a.setDinero();
        a.calculaMonedas();
    }
}
```