# Suma de decimales dentro de un array

Tags: javascript

Tengo problemas al sumar decimales en un array.

Haciendolo de esta manera:

```js
   var array = [2.74, 48.39, 71.45, 85, 38.39];
    
    var sum  = 0;
    //console.log(array.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      console.log(array[i]);
      sum += array[i];
    }
    console.log(sum);
```

o de esta:

```js
var array = [2.74, 48.39, 71.45, 85, 38.39];
let sum = array.map(c => parseFloat(c)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(sum)
```

> Devuelve `245.97000000000003` pero debería ser `245.97`

como deberia sumar decimales de un array?

Comment: Eso es un [problema general de números de punto flotante](http://puntoflotante.org/errors/rounding/). Para que necesitas la precisión exacta?

Comment: Claro, no entiendo porque agrega esos decimales al sumar...

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/16597)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haz uso de la función `.toFixed()`, en este caso puntual `.toFixed(2)` te dará el resultado `245.97`.

> La función `.toFixed()` formatea un número con un número específico de dígitos a la derecha del decimal.

**El porque de esto**, se explica [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) si quieres leerlo, considero que la explicación sale del tema, ya que es puramente como se trata el tipo float computacionalmente. PD: El articulo esta en ingles lamentablemente.

Answer (score -3):

Has probado a darle formato a la salida con number_format($número, 2, '.', '');

[Aquí](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php) tienes el manual de php

Comment: Gracias pero es para angular 4+

Comment: Es verdad XD. Perdón