# ¿Por qué el redondeo funciona tan diferente?

Tags: c, coma-flotante, redondeo

Tengo un programa en **C** que realiza una serie de operaciones con datos y los muestra, y necesito que estos datos sean lo más precisos posible. Unos datos de ejemplo podrían ser los siguientes:

```
float a = 12300.395;
float b = 123000.395;
float c = 432100.395;
float d = 1234000.395;
float e = 4321000.395;
```

Como podéis comprobar, todos tienen la misma parte decimal. Pero si los intento mostrar en pantalla con dos decimales obtengo lo siguiente:

```
printf("%.2f\n", a); // 12300.39
printf("%.2f\n", b); // 123000.40
printf("%.2f\n", c); // 432100.41
printf("%.2f\n", d); // 1234000.38
printf("%.2f\n", e); // 4321000.50
```

Cada uno de ellos distinto del anterior. Y si los muestro sin ni siquiera redondear tengo los siguientes datos:

```
printf("%f\n", a); // 12300.394531
printf("%f\n", b); // 123000.398438
printf("%f\n", c); // 432100.406250
printf("%f\n", d); // 1234000.375000
printf("%f\n", e); // 4321000.500000
```

Mi objetivo sería que redondease con 2 decimales y `.395` quedase en `.40`, pero `.394` quedase en `.39`. Entiendo que una solución sería pasar todos los datos del programa de `float` a `double`, para tener el doble de precisión, aunque incluso así no me lo hace perfecto ya que me redondea todos a `.40` menos el último (variable 'e') a `.39`. La cuestión es:

- ¿Hay alguna posibilidad de hacer esto con floats?
- ¿Por qué motivo se está inventando esos números de la parte decimal que hacen fallar el redondeo?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Si necesitas precisión, y dado que los tipos de coma flotante (float y double) tienen limitaciones, tendrías que hacer uso de alguna biblioteca que te permita trabajar con decimales o precisión arbitraria, como [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) o pasarte a otros lenguajes como C# o Python que tengan tipos de datos más adecuados (`decimal`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lectura inicial recomendada: [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/463)

El tipo `float` tiene una precisión típica de 6 dígitos. Es decir, únicamente los primeros 6 dígitos del número son representativos... el resto es basura

```
//   SEIS DIGITOS | BASURA
float a = 12300.3   95;
float b = 123000    .395;
float c = 432100    .395;
float d = 123400    0.395;
float e = 432100    0.395;
```

Si quieres más precisión tienes que tirar a `double`, que dispone de hasta 12 dígitos de precisión (si mal no recuerdo).

Para obtener más información acerca de las capacidades de cada tipo de dato disponible en C, puedes hacer uso de la librería [`limits.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)