# Error en el producto de dos Números en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Alguien sabe porque pasa esto en JavaScript?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pusible dupliado de [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?
](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/92764)

Answer (score 5):

> Es un error con los números de tipo `float`. Debido a la naturaleza
>   binaria de su codificación, algunos números decimales no se pueden
>   representar con exactitud perfecta.

Para solucionarlo puedes utilizar el `toFixed` o `Math.Round`

```
var value = 3.3333333;
value.toFixed(2);
//Resultado: 3.34
```

Puedes leer este artículo http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/avoiding-problems-with-decimal-math-in-javascript.html

Comment: Gracias Alfredo por tu comentario, solo nota que la pregunta es: ¿Por qué sucede? y aparte de contestarla sugiero una solución.

Comment: +1 Está es la manera correcta de manejar los números de punto flotante en EcmaScript

Comment: La razon es que siempre va a existir un margen de error al representar numeros racionales incluyendo decimales periodicos utilizando un numero de bits finito. La precision es proporcional al numero de bits de representacion.

Answer (score 4):

> Es porque Javascript convierte los numeros internamente a **double**.
>   Esto genera un efecto llamado **Inexactitud de Punto Flotante**. Basta
>   con redondear el numero en el formato deseado usando funciones
>   numericas como Math.round, Math.floor, toFixed, etc.

Se pueden ver algunos ejemplos aqui

https://code.i-harness.com/es/q/200d0a