# ¿Cómo evitar mostrar decimales en PHP?

Tags: php

Los valores que están entre `1, 2, 3, 4` me muestras decimales como resultados `0.2` al igual que los valores `11, 12, 13, 14` me muestra decimales como resultados `2.2` y así sucesivamente.

El redondeo funciona correctamente, por ejemplo si tengo valores de `5` me muestra como resultado `1` y si tengo valores de `10` me muestra un resultado de `2`.

Lo que deseo es eliminar las decimales, no mostrarla, porque el redondeo ya existe en mi variable todo valor que sea entre `5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30` me muestra resultados sin decimales, pero si son valores como `1, 2, 3, 4 7, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19` etc me muestra valores con decimales.

En resumen, solo deseo mostrar los valores redondeados y no los decimales.

Que condición le debo pasar a mi variable que me trae los valores:

```
echo $total;
```

Existe alguna herramienta como `number_format();` o otra que me permita eliminar los decimales y solo permitir los redondeados.

Comment: la función de php que redondea decimales a un entero es `round(3.4); // da 3`

Comment: El problema con round es que si tiene por ejemplo 3.6, daría 4. A menos que sea lo que necesite. Puedes usar substr();

Comment: @Alfredo El redondeo ya se trae de esa variable, por ejemplo si tiene este valor `5` me da resultado `1` si tengo este valor `45` me da resultado `9` entonces el redondeo ya existe, lo que deseo es ocultar o eliminar las decimales que se muestran al no llegar al redondeo.

Comment: @AndySamuel Voy a probar que sucede con `round`

Comment: @Alfredo Probé lo siguientes valores, valor de `7` me seguía mostrando el resultado de `1` pero si le cambie el valor a: `8` me cambio el valor a `2` y eso no es lo que deseo ese `2` debe mostrarse cuando el valor de la variable sea `10` y no `8`

Comment: Creo que no estoy entendiendo tu pregunta...

Comment: @AndySamuel Lo que deseo es eliminar las decimales, no mostrarla, porque el redondeo ya existe en mi variable todo valor que sea entre `5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30` me muestra resultados sin decimales, pero si son valores como `1, 2, 3, 4 7, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19` etc me muestra valores con decimales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es la función `floor()`

```
<?php 
    $num1 = 15.7;

    echo floor($num1); //Retorna 15
?>
```

Comment: voy a probar lo que has publicado.

Comment: Funciona tal como lo deseaba gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias opciones:

[`round($var);`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.round.php) redondeo con precisión

[`floor($var);`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.floor.php) redondeo para abajo

[`ceil($var);`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ceil.php) redondeo para arriba

si los resultados no son los esperados ver [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%C3%A9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%C3%A1lculos-aritm%C3%A9ticos-correctamente)