# Como ocultar <br><b> en un textarea

Tags: php, javascript, html, textarea

Estoy haciendo una plataforma de `streaming` tipo **YouNow**, ya hice todo pero tengo un problema con el **chat**.

Quiero hacer un chat donde el texto se vaya para arriba y no salir de ese cuadro, mi unica alternativa es un textarea.

pero ahora mi duda es como puedo ocultar los tags - ( < br > < b > < div > )

```html
<?php 
if ($_POST) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $content = $_POST['commentContent'];
    $handle = fopen("comentarios.php","a");
    fwrite($handle,"<b>".$name. "</b>:<br>". $content. "<br><br>");
    fclose($handle);
}



 ?>
 
 <textarea id="areadetexto">
                <div id="comentarios">
                <div id="comentario"> <?php include "comentarios.php"; ?><br/></div>
            </textarea>
```

El problema es que no encuentro ninguna informacion

Comment: Tu pregunta es como ocultar los tags? o como ocultar el texto?

Comment: ocultar los tags

Comment: Yo diría que no los pongas directamente

Comment: Puedes limpiar tu código `HTML` esto se suele llamar `sanitize`

Comment: posiblemente relacionado https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183212/81450, o usar `white-space: pre-wrap;word-wrap: break-word;` para que el texto no se vaya de caja. No relacionado pero lo usé en este ejemplo de mostrar cadenas de texto grandes (un número de 17000 cifras) dentro de un div https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/191224/81450, ó revertir los `BR` a saltos de línea onda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2436181/1423096

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tiene un mal enfoque, debido a que lo ideal sería que use un contenedor, y dentro muestre los mensajes con una etiqueta **p** que se genere de manera dinámica. Aun así puede hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<txtarea>
<pre>
hola
mundo
</pre>
</txtarea>
```

La etiqueta **pre** le permite mostrar texto **preformateado**, mostrando incluso la sangría y espacios.

Espero haberlo ayudado. Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

limpia el texto tramite js : 
`texto.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");` esta funcion te permite limpiar los tags del texto, espero que sea de ayuda