# Aproximación por exceso y por defecto (parecido a redondear) C++

Tags: c++, redondeo

¿Cómo se podría hacer para aproximar un número por defecto y por exceso?
Entendiendo que digamos, tenemos el número 2.534823

Una aproximación por defecto a 4 decimales, sería **2.5348**

y para aproximación por exceso a 4 decimales, sería **2.5349**

Es como hacer un redondeo pero para una posición de decimal especifica, ¿hay alguna manera de hacerlo en C++?

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo, pero sería únicamente para redondear al número **entero** más cercano, ya sea mayor o menor:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    
    float num;
    int deci;
    cout<<"\tCalcular aproximaciones por defecto y exceso"<<endl<<endl;
    
    cout<<"Ingrese un numero: " ;
    cin>>num;
    
    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de decimales"<<endl;
    cin>> deci;

    /*
        con ceil y floor me acerca al entero,
        ceil al entero más cercano mayor
        floor al  entero más cercano menor
    */
    
    cout<<"Aproximación por exceso: "<<ceil(num)<<endl;
    
    cout<<"Aproximación por defecto: "<<floor(num)<<endl;
    
    /*
       la aproximación debería quedar como:
       numero ingresado = 1.432986
       
       para por defecto  con 4 decimales, quedaria 1.4329
       para exceso con 4 decimales quedaría 1.4323
       pero con ceil, subiría a 2
       y con floor bajaría a 1

    
    */

    return 0;
}
```

En **C** Se podía truncar y/o redondear un número, a una cantidad especifica de decimales al imprimirlo (Es decir, la aproximación por defecto):

```
printf("%.3f", x);
```

Lo que quiero saber, es como se podría hacer lo mismo pero en **C++** y además obtener la aproximación por exceso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como [ya sabemos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/19610), los números en coma flotante son *imprecisos*, así que hacerlo directamente con el valor binario puede provocar resultados ... *curiosos*.

Una posible solución es realizar la aproximación sobre el valor **ya convertido a cadena**, si bien esto nos obliga a realizar ciertas operaciones *a mano*:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string upround( float value, unsigned decimals ) {
  std::stringstream buffer;

  buffer << value;

  // Cosas mias. `str( )` devuelve copias ... no vamos a estar todo el rato copiando cosas.
  std::string workCopy( buffer.str( ) );

  // Buscamos la posición del punto decimal.
  auto posOfPoint = workCopy.find( '.' );

  // Si es un número entero (sin punto), nada que hacer.
  if( posOfPoint == std::string::npos ) return workCopy;

  // Total de número a la derecha de la coma:
  auto workDecimals = workCopy.size( ) - 1 - posOfPoint;

  // Si hay menos decimales que los pedidos, nada que hacer.
  if( workDecimals < decimals ) return workCopy;

  // Recortamos la cadena.
  if( workDecimals > decimals ) workCopy.erase( workCopy.length( ) - ( workDecimals - decimals ) );

  // Trivial: el último dígito es != 9.
  if( workCopy.back( ) != '9' ) {
    ++( workCopy.back( ) );
  } else {
    // No trivial. El último dígito es un '9'. Es el caso 'chulo' :-)
    int pickup = 1;

    for( int idx = workCopy.length( ) - 1; idx >= 0; --idx ) {
      if( workCopy[idx] == '.' ) continue;
      workCopy[idx] += pickup;
      if( workCopy[idx] > '9' ) {
        workCopy[idx] = '0';
        pickup = 1;
      } else {
        pickup = 0;
        break;
      }
    }

    // Ya terminamos con la cadena.
    // Si aún nos queda 1 por sumar, hay que añadir un número al principio.
    if( pickup ) workCopy.insert ( 0, 1, '1' );
  }

  return workCopy;
}

int main( ) {
  const auto testValue = 3.1415f;
  std::cout << "Valor de prueba: " << testValue << '\n';
  std::cout << upround( testValue, 2 ) << '\n';
  std::cout << upround( testValue, 3 ) << '\n';

  const auto testValue2 = 9.9999f;
  std::cout << "Valor de prueba: " << testValue2 << '\n';
  std::cout << upround( testValue2, 3 ) << '\n';
  std::cout << upround( testValue2, 4 ) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

**No** lo he probado *a fondo*; para los valores de prueba ( `3.1415f` y `9.9999f` ) muestra lo siguiente:

> Valor de prueba: 3.1415
>   3.15
>   3.142
>   Valor de prueba: 9.9999
>   10.000
>   10.0000

<sub>Nota: es relativamente sencillo convertirlo a `template< >`, y, ya puestos, añadirle un argumento *extra* para poder usar otros separadores, aparte del punto (`.`).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Usa [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision), tu número con 3 decimales sería `2.535` y con 4 decimales sería `2.5348`, este código:

```
auto valor = 2.534823;

for (auto precision : {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})
    std::cout << std::setprecision(precision) << valor << '\n';
```

Produce la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 2.5
> 2.53
> 2.535
> 2.5348
> 2.53482
> 2.534823
> 2.534823
> 2.534823
> 2.534823
> ```

Puedes verlo funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uLR3XAW1umnO4fzE). Adicionalmente, puedes configurar el estilo de redondeo de números en coma flotante mediante [`std::fesetround`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround), teniendo [cuatro estilos de redondeo](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round):

- `FE_DOWNWARD`: Redondeo hacia negativo.
- `FE_TONEAREST`: Redondeo hacia el valor representable más cercano.
- `FE_TOWARDZERO`: Redondeo hacia cero.
- `FE_UPWARD`: Redondeo hacia positivo.

Con redondeo hacia negativo, el programa anterior:

```
std::fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);

for (auto precision : {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})
    std::cout << std::setprecision(precision) << valor << '\n';
```

Muestra la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 2.5
> 2.53
> 2.534
> 2.5348
> 2.53482
> 2.534822
> 2.5348229
> 2.53482299
> 2.534822999
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Tenemos este código en C que trunca y redondea un double

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double x = 32.588987;
    printf("%3f", x);
    return 0;
}
```

El equivalente de este código en C en C++ es este:

```
#include <iostream>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double x = 32.588987;
    std::cout.precision(6); // Establezca la precisión en 6 dígitos
    std::cout << std::fixed << x; // Usar notación de punto fijo
    return 0;
}
```