# Quitar decimales innecesarios a un número

Tags: javascript

He probado con floor(), round(), truncat() y ceil() y no me funciona (me redondea, pero no quiero redondear, quiero quitar decimales innecesarios). Si una función me devuelve esto:

```
// 0.5000000000000002
// 94.99000000000001
```

Busco un método que me los convierta a esto:

```
0.5
94.99
```

Comment: de hecho dices que no quieres redondear, pero en tu segundo ejemplo si redondeas, pues pasas de 94.99 a 95

Comment: @αλρθα Cierto, voy a actualizar el post!

Comment: @JavierCake te actualice el 95.99 ;)

Comment: relacionado [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%C3%A9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%C3%A1lculos-aritm%C3%A9ticos-correctamente)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo intentaría hacer un fix primero para quedarme solo con un decimal y después un replace con un regex para eliminar los 0 irrelevantes

```
(0.5000000000000002).toFixed(1).replace(/\.0+$/,'');
```

Aquí una versión algo mas compleja pero que cubre tus necesidades

```
(94.99000000000001).toFixed(2).replace(/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+[1-9])?)(\.?0+$)/,'$1')
```

```js
 console.log(
(0.5000000000000002).toFixed(2).replace(/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+[1-9])?)(\.?0+$)/,'$1')
)
    console.log(
(94.99000000000001).toFixed(2).replace(/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+[1-9])?)(\.?0+$)/,'$1')
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo que necesitas es hacer un `toFixed` al número. Por ejemplo

```js
console.log((94.99000000000001).toFixed())
console.log((0.5000000000000002).toFixed(1))
```

Puedes determinar el número de decimales que deseas aplicar pasando el método `toFixed()`

Answer (score 3):

Creo que esto te servirá:

```
var num = 94.99000000000001
Math.round(num) //95

var num2 = 0.5000000000000002
parseFloat(num2.toFixed(1)) //0.5
```

Comment: Por favor, explica por qué y cómo funciona tu código para que sea de utilidad para otros desarrolladores menos experimentados