# Porque en JavaScript la operacion de dos variables (25725.55-25725.54) igual a 0.00999999999839929?

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos varibles `

```js
 let TotalASaldar =25725.55 
 let totalAbonos=25725.54
 console.log(TotalASaldar - totalAbonos)
```

así valen exactamente.

la operacion: TotalASaldar - totalDeAbonos debería dar 0.1 pero la computadora calcula 0.00999999999839929 usando JavaScript

y este resultado me provoca problemas en las demás parte del código

¿Cómo se logra que me de el resultado 0.01?

Comment: Amigo te invito a que leas este articulo donde se habla mas profundo el tema de decimales https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%C3%A9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%C3%A1lculos-aritm%C3%A9ticos-correctamente

Comment: no es algo raro de JavaScript, Muchos lenguajes de programación, según el estándar IEE754, representan números en una representación de coma flotante en la base binaria.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver debes apoyarte de la funcion toFixed(N);
N representa el numero de decimales que aproximaras

```js
 let TotalASaldar =25725.55 
 let totalAbonos=25725.54
 let aux = TotalASaldar - totalAbonos;
 console.log(aux.toFixed(2))
```