# Multiplicación errónea?

Tags: python

Estaba viendo que en javascript el multiplicar `2.05` por `100` no da el resultado exacto, haciendo lo mismo en python me doy cuenta que tampoco lo hace.

```
2.05*100
```

resultado

> 204.99999999999997

Estuve investigando un poco y parece ser que para multiplicar utiliza el algoritmo de Karatsuba, pero haciendo el calculo no debería dar ese resultado, alguien sabe que algoritmo usan los lenguajes, o porque esa multiplicación sale de esa manera? gracias

Comment: Creo que deberías pasarte por esta otra pregunta: [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/149531)

Comment: Gracias, pensaba que era mas por el algoritmo que por el estándar, busque antes de preguntar pero no encontré esa pregunta