# Cast de double a int (sin redondeo)

Tags: c

Tengo una variable de tipo `double` llamada **x** a la que le realizo un **cast** al tipo de dato `int`. El problema es que durante la conversión se redondea el valor y quiero evitar eso.

La variable **x** antes de realizar el **cast** imprimo por pantalla y arroja 112.000000, pero luego al imprimir la otra variable arroja 111. No se porque este pasando esto.

En el código:

```
 double x = operacion + aritmetica; // Operacion que resulta 112.000000
 int    cast = (int) x;

 printf("%d", cast); // cast es 111
```

He probado con la funcion `trunc` pero sigue comportandose igual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso sucede porque `x` no vale exactamente 112.0000 sino 111.999999999999 y el sistema lo redondea a 112 debido a la incapacidad de mostrarte infinitos decimales.

Luego conviertes ese doble en un entero y los decimales se pierden, quedando el famoso 111.

Si esto es un problema puedes usar `round()`, que te redondeará el doble al entero más cercano:

```
111.6 -> 112
```

o bien puedes hacer una suma simbólica:

```
int cast = (int)(x + 1e-5);
```

De esta forma un número lo suficientemente cercano a 112, pero sin llegar a tal cifra, se transformará como por arte de magia en el tan ansiado 112

Adicionalmente te aconsejo leer esta otra pregunta:

- [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/463)