# Cómo corrijo este error validando medida en Python?

Tags: lista, funciones, condiciones, python-3.7, input

no logro que funcione me tira error, soy nuevo en python, me pueden ayudar?

```
       dxs1 = [1.55, 1.56, 1.57, 1.58]
       ds1 = [1.59, 1.60, 1.61, 1.62] 
       dm1 = [1.63, 1.64, 1.65, 1.66] 
       dl1 = [1.67, 1.68, 1.69, 1.70] 
       print (dl1)
       #ingreso una medida

       n = input ("ingrese su altura :   "  )


> #a partir de esa medida me devuelva en que talle entra

       if n == dl1:
          print ("usted es talle L")
       elif  n == dm1 :
          print ("Usted es talle M") 
       elif n == (ds1):
          print ("Usted es talle S") 
       elif n == (dxs1):
          print ("Usted es talle XS")     
       else :
          print ("usted es Ees un talle especial")
```

no logro que ande soy nuevo me pueden ayudar
se me complica para entrar un valor medida y que me devuelva lo que quiero.

Comment: Agrega el mensaje de error que obtienes

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma podría ser con diccionarios, donde cada item tendría como llave (`key`) el tipo de talla y como valor (`value`) una tupla correspondiente al rango de altura de esa talla.
Esto es mucho más ***escalable***, puedes modificar los rangos, quitar o agregar más, sin alterar el código posterior.

Como se puede observar, se inicializa `su_talla` como `'Especial'`. Si no se cumple ningún rango dentro del `for` entonces esa será la talla final para el usuario.

```
tallas = {'XS':(1.55,1.58), 'S':(1.59,1.62), 'M':(1.63,1.66), 'L':(1.67,1.70)}
n = float(input("ingrese su altura : "))
su_talla = 'Especial'
for key, value in tallas.items():
    if value[0] <= n <= value[1]:
        su_talla = key

print("Usted es una talla {}".format(su_talla))
```

Answer (score 0):

Te comento los problemas que tienes en el código:

- Cuando usas `input`, el resultado es texto, un string. Por tanto no puedes compararlo con un número. Esto lo puedes arreglar así:

  ```
  n = float(input ("ingrese su altura :   "))
  ```
- Aunque ya tengas un número, tienes el problema de que quieres compararlo con una lista, cuando lo que realmente quieres es saber si el número está en la lista:

  ```
  if n in dl1:
      ...
  ```
- De todos modos, sabiendo [los problemas que los números con coma flotante dan problemas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%C3%A9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%C3%A1lculos-aritm%C3%A9ticos-correctamente), podrías hacer lo siguiente, sin necesidad de usar listas:

  ```
  dl_min = 1.67
  dl_max = 1.70

  if dl_min < n < dl_max:
      print ("usted es talle L")
  ```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha ayudado, podrías marcarla como aceptada y así la pregunta aparecerá como "respondida". No es obligatorio, claro.