# Problema con scanf long doble

Tags: c

Necesito entrar por teclado dos numeros de 30 digitos por lo cual lo manejo con long doble, pero cuando lee el número por tecleado no se almacenan correctamente, como si el scanf no funcionara y no sé el porqué se presenta esto

```
long double entero, entero2;

printf("Ingrese el primer entero: \n");
scanf("%Lf",&entero);
printf("Ingrese el segundo entero \n");
scanf("Lf",&entero2);
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente)

Comment: No, ya lo había visto anteriormente pero te agradezco

Comment: ¿Que resultado da por pantalla?

Comment: Imprimiendo los dos enteros me muestra: 0.000000, el mismo número para ambos

Comment: ¿haces otro scanf antes, en ese mismo programa?

Comment: otra cosa, en el segundo scanf se has dejado el '%' (interpreto que no es ese el fallo)