# Como puedo sumar numeros muy pequeños en javaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Javascript y estaba jugando un poco con el código, el problema es que quiero hacer un ciclo que sume una cantidad muy pequeña de números repetidas veces pero a partir del 5to o 6to ciclo todo se descontrola, alguien que sepa que pasa y me lo explique.

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log("Hello world"), 0);
var milisegundo = 0.0001;
var total = 0;
var ciclos = 10;
for (var i = 0; i <= ciclos; i++) {
  console.log(total);
  total += milisegundo;
  if (i === ciclos) {
  console.log(`El programa tardo ${total} en finalizar`)
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente)

Answer (score 2):

Los números de punto flotante no son precisos, por eso los resultados,  puedes aplicar varias estrategias para redondear la cifra, por ejemplo:

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log("Hello world"), 0);
var milisegundo = 0.0001;
var total = 0;
var ciclos = 10;

for (var i = 0; i <= ciclos; i++) {
    console.log(total.toFixed(4))
    total += milisegundo;
    if (i === ciclos) {
        console.log(`El programa tardo ${total.toFixed(4)} en finalizar`)
    }
}
```

Otra sería aplicando una división:

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log("Hello world"), 0);
var milisegundo = 1;
var total = 0;
var ciclos = 10;

for (var i = 0; i <= ciclos; i++) {
    console.log(total/10000)
    total += milisegundo;
    if (i === ciclos) {
        console.log(`El programa tardo ${total/10000} en finalizar`)
    }
}
```

Comment: Genial amigo muchas gracias por tu ayuda.