# ¿Por qué se introducen decimales en una suma simple?

Tags: python, python-3.x

La suma simple de números con 4 decimales no se hace correctamente. Por ejemplo, *0,2222 + 0,6666 = 0,88879999999999999*. El código sería el siguiente:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)

contador = 0
ncfs = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    contador = contador + 1

    sc = line.find(":")
    nc = line[sc+1:]
    ncse = nc.strip()
    ncf = float(ncse)
    ncfs = ncfs + ncf

media = ncfs/ contador
print("Average spam confidence:", media)
```

Para ver donde se produce el error, no haría falta más que imprimir las variables: `ncf` y `ncfs`.

Mi objetivo no es lograr un resultado final, si no entender por que sucede esto así. Les agradezco la ayuda o explicación de por qué sucede esto. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente)

Comment: ¿Dónde está el error entonces? ¿Qué resultado te da? ¿Cual debería dar?

Comment: ***Les agradezco la ayuda o explicación de por qué sucede esto*** Esa explicación está en esta otra pregunta: [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente). Tu pregunta terminará cerrada como *duplicada*. Saludos