# ¿Cómo obtener el valor exacto de las funciones sin(), cos() o tan() en C++?

Tags: c++, matemáticas

Estoy intentando obtener el valor del coseno de diferentes ángulos en C++, pero, por ejemplo es bien sabido que el coseno de 360 es 1, sin embargo la función cos() da -0.2 y no entiendo la razón de ese resultado, lo mismo sucede con la función sin() que devuelve 0.95. He intentado convertir el valor resultante a grados debido a que las funciones cos(), sin(), etc. devuelven el valor en radianes, pero el resultado sigue siendo diferente a los valores que ya se conocen de ángulos como el de 360. No sé cómo obtener el valor correcto. Cualquier ayuda es agradecida.

```
    double op, op2, pot, real, img, r, ang, cosR, senR;

    cout << "Ingrese potencia" << endl;
    cin >> pot;
    cout << "Ingrese la parte real de la ecuacion" << endl;
    cin >> real;
    cout << "Ingrese la parte imaginaria de la ecuacion" << endl;
    cin >> img;

    r = pow(sqrt((real * real) + (img * img)), pot); //calcula la parte real

    ang = atan(img / real) * (180 / pi); //calcula el angulo y lo convierte a grados

    if (real > 0 && img > 0) //si ambas partes de la ecuacion estan en el cuadrante I
    {
        op = pot * ang; //ejemplo: 8 * 45 = 360

        cosR = cos(op); //esto da -0.283 cuando debería dar 1

        senR = sin(op); //esto da 0.95 cuando debería dar 0

        if (senR == 0) //debido a que el resultado de senR /= 0 el condicional no se ejecuta
        {
            cout << "--------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "Z^" << pot << " = " << r * (cosR + senR)  << endl;
            cout << "--------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Las funciones de C esperan el argumento en radianes, no en grados. Así que en vez de `cos(180)` debes probar `cos(2*pi)` y verás cómo ahí sí te sale 1. Puedes pasar de grados a radianes multiplicando por `pi/180`.

Comment: Ah, pues si funciona con `cos()`, pero no entiendo porque con el `sin()` sigue saliendo un resultado completamente diferente. Ej: `sin(180*(pi/180))` me da como resultado `1.22465e-16`. Y pues ya estoy haciendo la conversión de grados a radianes.

Comment: Eso se debe a errores de redondeo. Los números de punto flotante no tienen precisión infinita, en algún punto los decimales se cortan. Por tanto eso causa errores que se pueden ir acumulando. Esa es la razón por la que el seno no te sale exactamente 0.0, sino "casi cero" (10^-16)

Comment: Ahh, vale, ok hice uso de la función `round()` quedando algo cómo esto: `round(sin(180))` y da 0. Pero, por ejemplo `round(sin(45))` da 1 lo cual es un resultado un poco impreciso siendo que el seno de 45 es ~0.7 ¿hay alguna manera de lograr el resultado con esa misma precisión?

Comment: round te redondea al entero mas proximo, no me parece buena idea para un seno, que esta siempre entre 0 y 1 :-) No, el problema no se arregla redondeando. En realidad no tiene arreglo porque es una limitación del punto flotante. Lo que puedes hacer es reducir el numero de decimales a mostrar para que no se note (`cout.precision(7)`, por ejemplo)

Comment: Ok entiendo, pero lo que pasa es que no necesito mostrar, necesito operar o una forma de operar el resultado de seno logrando que dicho resultado sea preciso y correcto, sería muy válido usar `cout.precision(7)` si solo fuera a mostrar el resultado en pantalla. A lo mejor me estoy haciendo entender un poco mal; por ejemplo seno de 45 es igual a 0.70, básicamente de todo el resultado que da la función necesito el 0.7.

Comment: Además estaba probando y la función cos() si devuelve el valor correcto si el el número dado está en radianes, pero la función sin() no. No se si eso se deba a algún bug o algo como eso.

Comment: No se si eres consciente que has puesto `sin(45)`, cuando deberías haber puesto `sin(45*M_PI/180.0)`. Nota que en C++ tienes una macro `M_PI` ya definida en la librería `cmath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> por ejemplo es bien sabido que el coseno de 360 es 1, sin embargo la función cos() da -0.2

La funciones trigonométricas en C++ esperan la entrada en radianes, no en grados. Tienes que convertir los ángulos a radianes para obtener resultados correctos

> Ah, pues si funciona con cos(), pero no entiendo porque con el `sin()` sigue saliendo un resultado completamente diferente. Ej: `sin(180*(pi/180))` me da como resultado 1.22465e-16

La aritmética en coma flotante no es exacta. Es imposible representar muchísimos números decimales con un conjunto finito de 1s y 0s. Esto hace que las operaciones en coma flotante no den resultados exactos.

Puedes obtener más información sobre este punto en esta pregunta [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%C3%A9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%C3%A1lculos-aritm%C3%A9ticos-correctamente)

Adicionalmente, piensa que el número PI es un número irracional con, al menos, varios millones de decimales. La representación de dicho número que tu puedes usar en un programa tiene un número de decimales limitado, los cálculos que puedas hacer usando dicho valor tendrán igualmente una precisión limitada

> Ahh, vale, ok hice uso de la función `round()` quedando algo cómo esto: `round(sin(180))` y da 0.

Piensa que los valores devueltos por `sin()` y `cos()` van a oscilar **siempre** entre 0 y 1, si usas `round()` con el valor devuelto con cualquiera de estas dos funciones obtendrás generalmente un 0. Esto es así porque la función `round()` redondea sin decimales.

Por cierto, nota que has vuelto a usar grados en vez de radianes

> Pero, por ejemplo `round(sin(45))` da 1 lo cual es un resultado un poco impreciso siendo que el seno de 45 es ~0.7

Si atendemos al siguiente [ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ddl17iA1o7gUbSUV), vemos que `sin(45)` da como resultado 0.7071067812. Si preguntamos en [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%2845*PI%2F180%29), vemos que el resultado debería parecerse a 0.7071067811865475244008443621048490392848359376884740365883398689

Así pues la precisión vemos que es bastante buena, los primeros 9 decimales son correctos.

La única forma que yo he conseguido que me de un resultado cercano a 0.8 es haciendo `sin(45/M_PI*180)`, es decir, ahora no estoy calculando radianes sino ... otra cosa. Si este ha sido tu caso te sugiero no pasar de grados a radianes de forma manual. Crea una función que haga esta operación por ti. Así te evitarás errores molestos:

```
double ToRad(double degrees)
{
    return degrees * M_PI / 180;
}
```

**Conclusión**

Los cálculos trigonométricos que te ofrece la librería `cmath`, si bien no son ultraperfectos, si son bastante precisos y sirven bien para utilidades de propósito general. Estas funciones se usan en multitud de programas actuales con buenos resultados.

La precisión que te ofrecen es adecuada para la mayoría de situaciones y solo si necesitas mayor precisión tendrías que optar por buscar una librería de terceros más especializada o currarte el código a mano.

En cualquier caso, lo dicho, todas esas funciones están bastante probadas. Si obtienes resultados incorrectos lo más normal es que se deba a que estás haciendo mal los cálculos. Puede ser también un problema de la librería, pero eso es complicado salvo que estés usando un compilador *casero* cuya implementación de la librería estándar no haya sido debidamente testeada.

Comment: Si entiendo las operaciones de las funciones trigonométricas, pero estaba confundido debido a que el valor del coseno si era aproximado al valor real y el del seno era algo completamente erróneo y las pruebas que estaba haciendo era simplemente que lo mostrara en pantalla, de ahí la duda de si se trataba de un bug o algo. Lo que pude concluir; es mejor pasar a radianes cualquier número que vaya a operar las funciones y luego si se requiere pasar el resultado a grados.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, probablemente esta cuestión sobre las funciones para algunos sea demasiado obvia, pero bueno. Ahora, el resultado que devuelven las funciones depende de los parámetros o de la unidad de medida en la que estén. Por ejemplo

```
ang = atan(numA / numB);
```

Lo anterior, en las pruebas que hice devuelve el valor en radianes de dos parámetros cualquieras, se podría decir que el resultado siempre va a ser similar al obtenido por una calculadora o algún software propio para matemáticas y no se está haciendo ninguna conversión previa, aún así parece funcionar. Luego:

```
cosR = cos((numC * ang));
```

Lo anterior devuelve el coseno de la multiplicación entre el ángulo y otro número, funciona sin ningún tipo de conversión a radianes, pero mi explicación a esto es que el resultado de `ang` estaba en radianes, entonces al multiplicarse con el otro número queda dicho resultado en radianes y como la función `cos()` espera un resultado en radianes entonces la precisión es mayor y correcta. Pero:

```
senR = sin((numC * ang));
```

Cuando intento la misma operación con el seno el número que devuelve es incorrecto. Incluso con la conversión hecha por separado el resultado que retorna la función es completamente incorrecto. Sin embargo, la forma en la que pude hacer funcionar la función:

```
numD = numC * ang;
senR = sin((numD));
```

Haciendo la operación con la multiplicación por separado y luego pasando el resultado a la función hace que el número que retorna `sin()` sea correcto.

**Conclusión**

Las funciones trigonométricas en c++ no siempre van a devolver un valor correcto, para garantizar un resultado correcto lo mejor que se puede hacer es crear una función para hacer la conversión del número pasado a radianes o simplemente convertirlo antes de pasarlo como parámetro a la función. En mi caso la función seno era la única que no devolvía ningún resultado correcto y realmente no puedo explicar porque con la función arcotangente y coseno los resultados si eran correctos aún cuando no hacía ningún tipo de conversión de los parámetros a radianes.