# Omitir decimales float si suma no da decimales JS

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

tengo un código hecho a base de `<select></select>` en la que cada opción tiene un valor decimal, pero me lo envía como string, entonces yo lo paso a float con `parseFloat()`, pero da la casualidad de que en una combinación de `<option>` si tu haces la suma de los `value=""` da 423, pero Js me lo representa como 423.0000000001.

¿Cómo puedo omitir estos decimales?

Comment: Si solo querés formatear los números, podés usar [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed); de todas maneras, conviene que leas [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/156327)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para limitar los decimales solo tenemos que usar la función `toFixed()` para que convertirlo a entero o redondear a los decimales que necesitemos.

```
var numero = 9.46789; 
var conDecimal = numero.toFixed(2); 
// Igual a 9.47 
var entero = numero.toFixed(); 
// Igual a 9 (como un entero)
var con3decimales = numero.toFixed(3);
// Igual a 9.468
```

la variable `.toFixed()` convierte un número a cadena conservando los N primeros decimales.