# Como restar horas en HTML y JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

tengo una tabla vuetify que es una planilla de asistencia con 4 horarios , uno de entrada en la mañana, salida en la mañana , entrada en la tarde y salida en la tarde , necesito hacer una operación que me sume los horarios de las salidas menos la suma de los horarios de entradas ( (salida Mañana + salida tarde) - (entrada Mañana + entrada tarde) ) pero el resultado me da números que no son de horarios (por ejemplo 7.970000000000002 ) así que necesitaría pasarlo a formato horas pero no se hacerlo, alguien me ayuda?

HTML:

```
<v-data-table
id="tabla"
dense
:headers="headers"
:items="desserts"
item-key="name"
:page.sync="page"
:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
hide-default-footer
@page-count="pageCount = $event"
>
</v-data-table>
```

JavaScript:

```
  {
  dia        :'29',
  horaEntMan : '' ,
  horaSalMan : '' ,
  horaEntTar : '' ,
  horaSalTar : '' ,
  horas      : '' ,
  observacion: '' ,
  },

sumarHoras(){
  var i=-1;
   for(horas of this.desserts ){
    i=i+1;
  if(horas.horaEntMan.toString() != '-'){

    entrada1 = parseFloat(horas.horaEntMan.toString().replace(':','.'))

  }else{
    entrada1 = 0
  }

  if(horas.horaEntTar.toString() != '-'){

    entrada2 = parseFloat(horas.horaEntTar.toString().replace(':','.'))

  }else{
    entrada2 = 0
  }

  if(horas.horaSalMan.toString() != '-'){

    salida1 = parseFloat(horas.horaSalMan.toString().replace(':','.'))

  }else{
    salida1 = 0
  }

  if(horas.horaSalTar.toString() != '-'){

    salida2 = parseFloat(horas.horaSalTar.toString().replace(':','.'))

  }else{
    salida2 = 0
  }
  console.log(entrada1)
  console.log(entrada2)
  console.log(salida1 )
  console.log(salida2 )

  var calculo = (salida1 + salida2) - (entrada1 + entrada2)
  console.log('resultado: '+calculo)

  this.desserts[i].horas = calculo;
}
  // var entrada1 = parseFloat(this.desserts[0].horaEntMan.toString().replace(':','.'))
  // var entrada2 = parseFloat(this.desserts[0].horaEntTar.toString().replace(':','.'))
  // var salida1  = parseFloat(this.desserts[0].horaSalMan.toString().replace(':','.'))
  // var salida2  = parseFloat(this.desserts[0].horaSalTar.toString().replace(':','.'))
  // console.log(entrada1)
  // console.log(entrada2)
  // console.log(salida1 )
  // console.log(salida2 )

  // var calculo = (salida1 + salida2) - (entrada1 + entrada2)
  // console.log('resultado: '+calculo)



  // inicioMinutos = parseInt(entrada1.substr(3,2));
  // inicioHoras = parseInt(entrada1.substr(0,2));
  
  // finMinutos = parseInt(salida1.substr(3,2));
  // finHoras = parseInt(salida1.substr(0,2));

  // transcurridoMinutos = finMinutos - inicioMinutos;
  // transcurridoHoras = finHoras - inicioHoras;
  
  // if (transcurridoMinutos < 0) {
  //   transcurridoHoras--;
  //   transcurridoMinutos = 60 + transcurridoMinutos;
  // }
  
  // horas = transcurridoHoras.toString();
  // minutos = transcurridoMinutos.toString();
  
  // if (horas.length < 2) {
  //   horas = "0"+horas;
  // }
  
  // if (horas.length < 2) {
  //   horas = "0"+horas;
  // }
  
  // console.log(horas)
  // console.log(minutos)

},
```

una imagen pare tener como referencia de lo que muestro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: html y vuetify no tienen nada que ver con tu problema, no? probaste alguna libreria de fechas para hacer esto?

Comment: utilizo HTML y vuetify para hacer el proyecto ,pero no se si el problema venga de ahí sino de JavaScript  , y no utilice ninguna librería de fechas porque no se implementarlas

Answer (score 0):

##### Horas a decimales

Convertir horas en formato `hh:mm` a decimales no es tan sencillo como reemplazar el ":" por un ".". Se puede ver en que, `16:30` es `16.5` (16 horas , 30 minutos), NO `16.3` (16 horas, 18 minutos). Esto se debe a que estás trabajando con dos bases numericas diferentes (base 10 y base 60).

La formula que podemos usar para pasar horas y minutos a decimal es

```
hora + minuto / 60
```

Siendo el segundo termino el porcentaje de horas que representa el minuto en cuestión.

##### Separando horas y minutos

- Truncamos el número para obtener las horas: `Math.floor(t)`
- Y restamos ese resultado al número original, quedandonos con la parte decimal, y multiplicando por 60 para pasar a la base 60. Luego truncamos para evitar problemas de presición ([más información](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/204/158880)): `Math.floor((t - Math.floor(t)) * 60)`

##### Formateando la hora

Habiendo hecho las correspondientes cuentas, vas a querer que ese decimal se vea "como hora". Una forma de lograrlo es convertir los números en cadenas y agregar un 0 a la izquierda si resulta necesario (para esto sirve `String.padStart(2, "0")`, que indica "rellenar con ceros al inicio hasta que la cadena mida dos caracteres") y poner un ":" entre ambos resultados.

```
horas.toString().padStart(2, "0") + ":" + minutos.toString().padStart(2, "0")
```

##### Código

```js
function hourToDecimal(hora){
    let [h1, m1] = hora.split(":")
    return parseInt(h1) + parseInt(m1) / 60
}

function decimalToHour(t){
    let horas = Math.floor(t)
    let minutos = (t - horas) * 60
    
    horas = horas.toString().padStart(2, "0")
    minutos = Math.round(minutos, 2).toString().padStart(2, "0")
    
    return horas + ":" + minutos
}

let t = "6:30"
console.log("6:30 = ", hourToDecimal(t))
console.log("6:30 - 01:18 = ", decimalToHour(hourToDecimal(t) - 1.3))
```