# ¿Que tipo de dato puedo usar en Java para un decimal muy grande?

Tags: java, spring-boot, bigdecimal

Tengo un servicio que me regresa una lista de datos de la BD, hay campos que son de tipo decimal muy grandes, por ejemplo en la base de datos se muestra asi: **0.0000000013049999999999849460166767232170084219** y yo en mi entidad, hice el mapeo de ese campo como Double, y me lo pinta asi en mi log: **1.3049999999999848E-9**  despues lo cambie a tipo String y en mi log sale asi: **1.30499999999998494601667672321700842198E-09**,
que tipo de dato es el indicado para esta cantidad? o si uso Angular como podria mostrar ese numero como en la BD?

este es mi servicio

```
public ResponseEntity<?> consultar(String datenIni, String dateFin) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    List<ValuesDto> listVal = new ArrayList<ValuesDto>();
    try {
        listVal = consultRepository
                .consulValues(datenIni, dateFin);
        

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for ValuesDto Data");
        response.put("success", false);
        response.put("error", e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    response.put("success", true);
    response.put("data", listVal);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

y la entidad

```
@Entity
    @Table
    public class ValuesDto implements Serializable {

    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "IDREGISTRO")
    private Integer idRegistro;

    
    
    @Column(name = "NOOPCIONES")
    private Double noOpciones;

    
    @Column(name = "FECHACOTIZACION")
    private Date fechaCotizacion;

    
    }


System.out.println("PRUEBA OPCIONES: " +listVal.get(0).getNoOpciones());




BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(DECIMAL);

private static final String DECIMAL = "0.0000";
```

Comment: No sabemos cómo estás _pintando_ el Double. Tampoco sabemos eso qué relación tiene con Angular porque  tampoco hay código TS en tu pregunta. Una pregunta sin código es una pregunta incompleta.

Comment: ya agregue el codigo

Comment: Has buscado BigDecimal??

Comment: BigDecimal o BigInteger, investiga esos tipos de datos

Answer (score 2):

Para una revisión independiente del lenguaje sobre qué hacer al trabajar con alta precisión, revisa [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente/204#204).

Para saber cómo se comportan los tipos de dato, siempre es sano comenzar por los primitivos en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) y luego ver otras clases que podrían ser útiles.

Si necesitas alta precisión, el camino es comenzar a usar [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) y explorar otras [clases útiles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numbers.html).

Para darle formato a las cosas, dependiendo del dato, puedes usar printf con modificadores para flotantes (hasta 15 posiciones decimales, creo) o un NumberFormat (DecimalFormat es el que está en el ejemplo). Recuerda siempre que el guardar y el mostrar son dos problemas diferentes y deben resolverse por separado.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Pepito {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       
      try {

         double test = 0.0000000013049999999999849460166767232170084219;
         System.out.println("sencillo: " + test);
         System.out.printf("formateado: %.15f", test);
         
         
         BigDecimal test2 = new BigDecimal("0.0000000013049999999999849460166767232170084219");
         
         DecimalFormat pepe = new DecimalFormat("##.################################################################");
         
         System.out.println("\nBigDecimal: " + pepe.format(test2));
         


      } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

Eso va a mostrar en consola algo como:

```
sencillo: 1.3049999999999848E-9
formateado: 0.00000000130500000000
BigDecimal: 0.0000000013049999999999849460166767232170084219
```

Comment: gracias, me funciono asi, oye tengo una duda, debo de validar que ese campo no venga nullo o vacio, si es el caso debo setearle el valor 0,0000, adjunto como lo hice, pero no me toma completo, solo el 0, como puedo lograr setear el 0.0000?

Comment: si quiero setear ese valor pepe.format(test2), al objeto noOpciones que es de tipo BigDecimal, como seria? o sea es que en si  es el mismo objeto , noOpciones como comente regresa su valor en exponencial, aplicando lo que tu me enseñaste para que se muestre completo, como le asigno ese valor al objeto? para que ya no pinte el exponencial, o sea seterale al mismo objeto, no se si me explico

Comment: @Root93 revisa la documentación de esa clase. Tiene métodos para operar con el número, para compararlo con cero, con uno, para asignarle valores de formas diferentes... revísala y, si hay alguna otra duda, plantéala como una nueva pregunta (porque es una nueva pregunta) :)