# ¿Cómo funciona Delta y qué valor pasarle en Junit Java Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

Buen Dia, he empezado a realizar pruebas unitarias usando Junit pero tengo un dudad respecto a eso
En mi clase principal tengo este código sencillo

```
public double suma(double num1, double num2) {
    double suma = num1 + num2;
    return suma;
}
```

y en las clase donde hago las pruebas tengo esto

```
@Test
public void testSuma() {
    System.out.println("suma");
    double num1 = 4.1;
    double num2 = 5.2;
    Prueba instance = new Prueba();
    double expResult = 9.3;
    double result = instance.suma(num1, num2);
    assertEquals(expResult, result, 0.0);
    if (result != expResult) {
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }
}
```

No hay ningun error pero estuve buscando información sobre delta y decía que era para dar un margen de error en los decimales, pero aun no entiendo bien eso, podrían darme un ejemplo sobre ese punto?

Comment: Es exactamente lo que dices. Por ejemplo `assertEquals(1.0, 1.1, 0.0);` fallaría pero `assertEquals(1.0, 1.1, 0.2);` sería correcto porque la diferencia es menor que delta, digamos, es menor que el *"margen permitido"*. Eso se establece así porque las operaciones con punto flotante en informática no son nada fáciles de hacer. Lo que para ti es muy obvio para un pc no tanto. Aquí tienes una página interesante que lo explica: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Como extra: assertEquals se encarga ya de hacer que el test falle si no es verdad, el `if` es innecesario

Comment: hola @Benito-B, probé tu ejemplo `assertEquals(1.0, 1.1, 0.2);` pero la prueba falla

Comment: Fallará por tu `if (result != expResult) {
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }` pero te aseguro que esa aserción es válida. De hecho, acabo de lanzarla en un test por probar (la había escrito de memoria) y el test pasa perfecto... Pero que pase perfecto no quiere decir que luego tú no estés fallando el test más adelante (dentro del if... `fail` hace fallar el test exactamente igual que una aserción fallida).

Comment: @Benito-B Acabo de quitar el `if` pero la prueba igual falla, qué podría estar mal? solo he cambiado los valores por los tuyos en el código de arriba

Comment: @Benito-B acabo de realizar el test y pasa tal y como dices

Comment: Pero como haría para calcular el delta para ciertas cantidades?

Comment: no hay un único criterio para definir el delta. Depende del nivel de resolución que requieras.

Answer (score 1):

¿Revisaste la [documentación oficial](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/src-html/org/junit/Assert.html#line.484)? ¿Probaste tu código con diferentes valores? ¿No? Pues muy mal ;)

Ese *delta* permite fijar un márgen de error para el resultado. Puede que estés operando con variables de punto flotante y **ya sabemos** que ahí [no tienes absoluta precisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente/209#209) debido a la forma como se representan los valores numéricos en un lenguaje dado y cómo los manipula al operar sobre ellos.
Puede ser también que tu cálculo es muy sensible a variables como la hora o a valores aleatorios... casos así.

Por ejemplo, si vas a calcular algo y la respuesta puede ser `0.932874298374` o `0.9300000000` o `0.9399999999` por puras particularidades del cálculo entre variables... pero a ti sólo te interesa que tu escenario de prueba compruebe que el valor es `0.93`, pues usas este parámetro para que la comparación no falle por cifras significativas fuera de tu control. Estás ajustando el grado de precisión de la validación.

Si, por ejemplo, tienes tu clase de prueba y haces

```
private static final double DELTA = 0.5d;

@Test
public void testSuma() {
    System.out.println("suma");
    double num1 = 4.1;
    double num2 = 5.2;
    Prueba instance = new Prueba();
    double expResult = 9.3;
    double result = instance.suma(num1, num2);
    assertEquals(expResult, result, DELTA);
    if (result != expResult) {
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }
}
```

Esto internamente llama un método que valida `Math.abs(expResult - result) > DELTA` y, si eso da `true`, significa que el número es diferente. Si el valor absoluto de la diferencia entre los valores está por debajo de tu `delta` (menos de 0.5 por encima o por debajo en este ejemplo), para efectos prácticos serán iguales.