# Pregunta sobre declaracion de variables en java

Tags: java, poo, netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

saludos compañeros, tengo una duda con respecto a la imagen que les he pasado. la pregunta es:  porque tengo que declarar int 2 veces a la variable ganancia? al principio la tenia asi: int ganancia = inversion * 0.02 ; pero netbeans me marcaba un error y una de sus sugerencias fué esta.

Comment: Cuál era el mensaje de error que te daba netbeans? Por qué compartes código como imágen? Dónde está carmen sandiego? :P Recuerda que el código se comparte como texto; leer ese código es difícil dependiendo de cada persona y se hace difícil ayudarte. Estoy seguro que el mensaje de error de netbeans era autoexplicativo; suelen ser errores en tiempo de compilación

Comment: tu IDE  te reconoce  que `inversion*0.02` te va generar un dato de tipo  `double` (marca error) ahora ese valor generado esta asociado a `ganancia` que es de tipo `int` entonces tu IDE te surgiere `(int)(inverision*0.02)` a modo de convertir el dato `double` en `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sabemos cómo estaba tu código antes, pero es seguro que lo que estás haciendo ahí es un *casting*. Estás transformando algo (`inversion * 0.02`) en entero para podérselo asignar a `ganancia`.

La cosa es que, el resultado de hacer esa multiplicación **es seguro** que no va a ser un entero (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,... 100,...) y tiene pinta de ser un `double` o algún otro tipo de dato que maneje las cifras significativas. No tenías el casting (el `(int)` a la derecha del signo `=`) así que intentabas asignarle un `double` a un `int` y pues, hueco circular y cubito cuadrado, no encaja.

Como está tu programa, las estás ignorando y estás perdiendo precisión (estás convirtiendo 10.12 en 10). Que netbeans te sugiera algo para que *compile* no significa que ese **deba ser** el código en tu programa para tu problema. Posiblemente debas trabajar con `double` o, mejor aún, con `BigDecimal`.

Pásate por [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/6798) y su respuesta