# Resultado no esperado en el Incremento de For

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Estoy usando un for con un incremento de 0.2, Los resultados que imprime son 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6000000000000001, 0.8, y así llega a 9.999999999999996.

```js
for(let i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 0.2){
    console.log("Valor de incremento 0.2:",i);
}
```

Lo que quiero obtener es 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.4 hasta llegar a 10. Espero me puedan Ayudar, Muchas Gracias

Comment: Hay una pregunta que seguro alguno de los miembros mas conocidos de stackoverflow colocara aqui referente a eso, ya es bastante popular esa pregunta, pero en resumen, se debe a que no se pueden hacer operaciones muy exactas debido a e que el sistema que manejan los pc es binario.

Comment: En alguna parte ví porque es que javascript tiene problemas con los decimales. Daban una explicación razonable, para eso. Porque otros lenguajes de programación no tienen ese problema. Pero bueno hay unos videos que puedes encontrar como `problema de JAVASCRIPT y los DECIMALES` despues de verlo puedes entender como solucionarlo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por su ayuda!!

Comment: @AlexanderDiaz todos los lenguajes tienen un tipo `float` justo con esos mismos problemas, porque la mayoría  se basan en el estándar [IEEE_754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) para asegurar compatibilidad, la diferencia es que tienen otros tipos de datos en los que lo solucionan, como mismo en javascript se introdujo `BigInt`  para ello. Charles, si quieres "Parchear" de cierto modo el problema en tu caso particular, consume usa `toFixed` para redondear el número dentro del for: `console.log("Valor de incremento 0.2:",i.toFixed(1));`

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Cada día se aprende algo nuevo, no se porque tenía la impresión de que era solo en javascript.

Comment: Charles, [esta es la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%C3%A9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%C3%A1lculos-aritm%C3%A9ticos-correctamente/) qué mencionaba @Riven y es una lectura MUY RECOMENDADA. Está enfocada `lenguaje-agnóstico` porque es algo que te vas a encontrar en todos los lenguajes y más vale estar al tanto de ello.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente)

Answer (score 1):

Una de las mejores maneras para solucionar este problema es usar el Number y el toFixed()

```js
for(let i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 0.2){
    console.log("Valor de incremento 0.2:",Number(i.toFixed(1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre aumentar de a 2 unidades y dividirlo por 10

```
for(let i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 2){
console.log("Valor de incremento 0.2:",i/10);
```

}