# Double Impreciso

Tags: c#, double

El programa es una Distribución Poisson, pero cuando el número es muy grande, el factorial es impreciso y agrega algunas milésimas.

¿Como podría hacer más precisión el `double`? ¿O existe un valor con mayor tamaño?

```cs
for (int x = 0; x <= 15; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nx:{0} -------------------------- ", x);
    double num1 = Math.Pow(e, -lambda);
    double num2 = Math.Pow(lambda, x);

    double num = num1 * num2;

    fact = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
        fact = fact * i;
    }
    //Factorial

    double fxres = 0;
    fxres = num / fact;
    Console.WriteLine("F(x): " + fxres);
    fx+= fxres;
    Console.WriteLine("\nSuma: " + fx);

    number++;
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente)

Answer (score 0):

Si lo importante es la precisión, deberías usar el tipo Decimal. Si lo importante es la velocidad, usar double.

Decimal tampoco es 100% preciso ya que los decimales en informática son así ... finitos. Pero tiene más precisión que double.