# Python - 16 digitos Decimal

Tags: python

por qué

```
print(3 == 3.0000000000000007)
False
```

y este es TRUE

`print(3 == 3.00000000000000007)`

Por qué reconoce hasta 16 digitos que es un int?

gracias

Comment: Muy interesante pregunta. Supongo que es un tema de presición maxima. Pues si imprimes el flotante del segundo caso sale en pantalla 3.0, y claro, 3 y 3.0 son iguales. Pero Abulafia sabe mucho más que yo del tema.

Comment: no la voy a cerrar yo por este motivo, pero [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente) no contesta tambien esto?

Comment: Tu error es suponer que Python maneja el punto flotante con una cantidad ilimitada de decimales, tantos como tú le pongas. Lectura obligatoria: https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Python utiliza la clase `float` para representar números reales e internamente `CPython` implementa los `float` utilizando el tipo `double` del lenguaje C.

Python utiliza 8 bytes (64 bits) para representar los números reales (`float`) que cumplen con las siguientes funciones:

1 bit para el signo (Positivo o negativo)

11 bits para el exponente 1.5e-5 1.5 x 10-5 (El exponent es -5) y el rango es [-1022, 1023].

52 bits para dígitos significativos.

Por ejemplo, 0.25 tiene dos dígitos significativos, 0.125 tiene tres dígitos significativos y 12.25 tiene 4 dígitos significativos (Es decir, no considera los ceros a la izquierda ni a la derecha de los dígitos significativos).

Algunos números tienen un número finito de dígitos significativos, pero hay otros que no, por ejemplo 0.1 sería (Tiene un número infinito de dígitos significativos):

```
0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101...
```

Entonces lo que hace Python es aproximarlos

Un ejemplo:

```
x = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
y = 0.3

print(x == y)
```

Esto devolvería `False`

Y al revisar el valor de `x` y `y` con 20 dígitos significativos vamos a ver que son diferentes

```
print(format(x, '.20f'))
print(format(y, '.20f'))
```

Esto devuelve:

```
0.30000000000000004441
0.29999999999999998890
```

[PEP485](https://peps.python.org/pep-0485/) provee una solución que arreglaría este "problema". En la librería `math` agrega una función llamada `isclose()` que devuelve `True` si dos números son relativamente cercanos.

```
from math import isclose

x = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
y = 0.3

print(isclose(x,y))
```

Esto devuelve `True`

`isclose()` tiene los siguientes argumentos

```
isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-9, abs_tol=0.0)
```

En general no es recomendable comparar en igualación dos números reales `float` en ningún lenguaje de programación, por lo general se compara a un rango (Tolerancia) por lo que `isclose()` es una buena alternativa.

Fuentes:

[Python float](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-float/)

[15. Aritmética de Punto Flotante: Problemas y Limitaciones](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) (Recomendada por CandidMoe en los comentarios)

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias @HeytalePazguato