# PHP Round no redondea apropiadamente

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo el siguiente valor: **11.9945**

Necesito redondearlo a **12.00**

**He probado con :**

```
round($val,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
round($val,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
round($val,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);
```

y simpre me da como resultado **11.99**

En javascript tengo la siguiente funcion que si funciona como lo necesito:

```
var x = Math.pow(10, Number(decimals) + 1);
return (Number(number) + (1 / x)).toFixed(decimals);
```

Pero necesito hacerlo en PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo algunos ejemplos del por qué pasa eso:

```
<?php
// Precisión 3 decimales, toma los primeros 3 y aproxima el último según el valor
// de los decimales restantes (5), resultado -> 11.995
echo round(11.9945,3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

// Precisión 2 decimales, toma los primeros 2 y aproxima el último según el valor
// de los decimales restantes (45), resultado -> 11.99
echo round(11.9945,2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

// Precisión 0 decimales, aproxima el entero según  el valor de los decimales
// 11.9954 - > 12
echo round(11.9945,0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

// otra forma, redondear sin considerar decimales, 11.9945 -> 12

echo round(11.9945, 0)


?>
```

[Referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.round.php)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero habrá alguna forma de redondear manteniendo los decimales? Necesito que el resultado sea 12.00, lo extraño es que en Javascript funciona bien

Answer (score 1):

Umm.. Quizás esto te ayude:

```
$num = round(11.99);
$number = sprintf('%.2f', $num);
echo($number)
```

No es lo ideal pero podría servirte (a mi humilde opinion)

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que aunque hagas esto: `round(11.99, 2)` internamente seguirá siendo un flotante por lo que no será representado de forma exacta por la computadora. Esto es así en todos los lenguajes.

Ver: [Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos correctamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197/80870).

Sugiero trabajes internamente de forma natural con los decimales que maneje el lenguaje y al momento de imprimir la salida, entonces hagas el redondeo/truncamiento correspondiente.

```php
php > $var = 50000 / 3.743;
php > echo $var;
13358.268768368
php > echo round($var, 2);
13358.27 // Flotante redondeado, pero no se garantiza siempre su representación
php > echo sprintf('%0.2f', $var);
13358.27 // cadena
php > echo number_format($var, 2);
13,358.27 // cadena
php > echo number_format($var, 2, '.', '');
13358.27 // cadena
php > echo number_format($var, 2, ',', '.');
13.358,27 // cadena
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue la solución por si alguien tiene el mismo problema que yo:

```
function round_up( $value, $precision ) { 
$pow = pow ( 10, $precision ); 
return ( ceil ( $pow * $value ) + ceil ( $pow * $value - ceil ( $pow * $value ) ) ) / $pow; }
```

La función redondea hacia arriba mantenimiento los 2 decimales