# Error con suma de senos y cosenos

Tags: java

Hola tengo que realizar un programa acerca de la descomposición de fuerzas y al querer sumar el resultado de las operaciones de seno y de coseno me da un resultado incorrecto en los dos casos, he intentado modificar las operaciones, incluso los tipos de datos pero nada funciona

Este es el código:

dato=new Datos();

```
     dato.setMagnitud1(Double.parseDouble(txtMag1.getText()));
     dato.setMagnitud2(Double.parseDouble(txtMag2.getText()));
     dato.setMagnitud3(Double.parseDouble(txtMag3.getText()));
     dato.setMagnitud4(Double.parseDouble(txtMag4.getText()));
     dato.setMagnitud5(Double.parseDouble(txtMag5.getText()));
     dato.setAngulo1(Double.parseDouble(txtAng1.getText()));
     dato.setAngulo2(Double.parseDouble(txtAng1.getText()));
     dato.setAngulo3(Double.parseDouble(txtAng3.getText()));
     dato.setAngulo4(Double.parseDouble(txtAng4.getText()));
     dato.setAngulo5(Double.parseDouble(txtAng5.getText()));
     
     
    dato.setResult1(dato.getMagnitud1()*(Math.cos(dato.getAngulo1())));
    dato.setResult2(dato.getMagnitud2()*(Math.cos(dato.getAngulo2())));
    dato.setResult3(dato.getMagnitud3()*(Math.cos(dato.getAngulo3())));
    dato.setResult4(dato.getMagnitud4()*(Math.cos(dato.getAngulo4())));
    dato.setResult5(dato.getMagnitud5()*(Math.cos(dato.getAngulo5())));
    
    dato.setSin1(dato.getMagnitud1()*(Math.sin(dato.getAngulo1())));
    dato.setSin2(dato.getMagnitud2()*(Math.sin(dato.getAngulo2())));
    dato.setSin3(dato.getMagnitud3()*(Math.sin(dato.getAngulo3())));
    dato.setSin4(dato.getMagnitud4()*(Math.sin(dato.getAngulo4())));
    dato.setSin5(dato.getMagnitud5()*(Math.sin(dato.getAngulo5())));
    
    dato.setSumX(dato.getResult1()+dato.getResult2()+dato.getResult3()+dato.getResult4()+dato.getResult5());
    dato.setSumX(dato.getSin1()+dato.getSin2()+dato.getSin3()+dato.getSin4()+dato.getSin5());
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente)

Comment: Espero que hayas tenido en cuenta que `Math.sin` y `Math.cos` lo que recibe como argumento es un valor en radianes y no en grados. ¿Lo tuviste en cuenta? ¿Estás pasando el valor del ángulo en radianes?