# ¿Cómo usar decimales en una operación relacional en C?

Tags: c, operador, float

Estoy haciendo un código que muestre en pantalla el uso de la precedencia de operadores relacionales. Para ello, uso tres valores decimales (a, b, c) y los operadores "diferente de (!=)" y "mayor igual que (>=)"

El programa debe arrojar el valor de 1 cuando la declaración sea verdadera, y 0 cuando sea falsa; sin embargo, siempre me da un valor de 1.

Dejo mi código a continuación, esperando puedan ayudarme a implementarlo correctamente.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    float a = 1.1;
    float b = 1.01;
    float c = 0.101;
        printf("%d", c>=a!=b);
        printf("\n %d", c!=a>=b);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No recuerdo exactamente como es que pasa, pero tu primera operacion no te deja un float, y luego de alli las comparaciones ya no son en float.. algun experto te lo va a explicar mejor

Comment: @gbianchi Muchas gracias, plantearé mejor mi pregunta. El "resultado" debe ser un entero, toda vez que determinará si la operación es verdadera (1) o falsa (0)... Probé poniendo los valores (decimales) directamente en lugar de las variables, pero daban el mismo resultado (siempre arroja 1).

Comment: Lo que te puedo decir es que por [precedencia de operadores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) `c>=a!=b` es equivalente a `(c>=a) != b`. `c>=a` es falso. Para evaluar `false != b`, `false` se convierte a entero (0) y este a float (0). Entonces `0 != b` es verdadero. Algo similar ocurre con la segunda expresión. Puedes ver más en el panel derecho de [esta página](https://cppinsights.io/s/9ff42906) luego de presionar el botón de play.

Comment: @Mateo Muchas gracias por tu comentario. Disculpa que te pregunte, pero si (por ejemplo) tengo la expresión `b!=c>=a` que es equivalente a `1 >= 1.1`, se debería evaluar como falsa (0); sin embargo, en mi programa arroja un valor afirmativo (1). ¿A qué se debe y cómo puedo corregirlo?

Comment: Es la misma expresión que te expliqué. La idea era que te pueda orientar para aclarar la pregunta porque no me queda claro. ¿Se supone que hay que tener en cuenta los valores de a b y c del código o los que agregaste en la última edición? Porque en el otro comentario usé los valores del código.

Comment: @Mateo Se supone que son los valores del código, por lo que el programa debería leer la expresión `b!=c>=a` como `1.01 != 0.101 >= 1.1`. Por precedencia de operadores, esta expresión es distinta a `c>=a!=b`. Lo que comenté en la anterior edición fue que, haciendo pruebas, pude darme cuenta que (cuando uso dos operadores relacionales en una misma expresión) no toma los valores como decimales, sino que los redondea.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente)

Comment: `b != c >= a` se asocia de la manera `b != (c >= a)`. Es equivalente a `c >= a != b` que se asocia como `(c>=a) != b` ya que el operador `!=` es conmutativo. Sugeriría que hagamos un [chat] para seguir la discusión, pero creo que aún no tienes suficiente reputación. Te invito a que leas detenidamente la [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) y lo compruebes con el [código máquina](https://godbolt.org/z/6fsr9E8Ya) que genera el compilador.

Comment: Ya quedó claro, muchísimas gracias por todos sus comentarios.