# Math.Round no redondea por igual dos decimales similare

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un caso muy curioso entre manos que en parte he resuelto pero me pregunto si hay alguna otra solución y el motivo del comportamiento de cuanto voy a exponer.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    double value1 = 198.275;
    double value2 = 273.275;
    
    Console.WriteLine("Round: " + Math.Round(value1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    Console.WriteLine("Round: " + Math.Round(value2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    Console.WriteLine();
    
    Console.WriteLine("ToString #: " + (value1).ToString("#.##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Console.WriteLine("ToString #: " + (value2).ToString("#.##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Console.WriteLine();
    
    Console.WriteLine("ToString N: " + (value1).ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Console.WriteLine("ToString N: " + (value2).ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

La salida de éste código es la siguiente:

```
Round: 198.28
Round: 273.27

ToString #: 198.28
ToString #: 273.28

ToString N: 198.28
ToString N: 273.28
```

Cómo se puede ver en las dos primeras líneas, el redondeo entre el valor1 y el valor2 es distinto.
Me pregunto el porque de este comportamiento y si hay más soluciones además de las dos que he encontrado.

La idea es que al redondear dos números con iguales decimales, me devuelva el mismo redondeo (cómo en los últimos cuatro resultados del ejemplo).

Adjunto enlace a Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VyqTcv

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema no es del método con que redondeas, el problema es típico error del punto flotante.

Primero cabe aclarar que un double es un float de doble precisión, es decir, funciona como lo hace un float. Luego el float tiene problemas en la representación de fracciones, esto sucede porque al transformar a binario puede no existir una serie de potencias (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...) que coincida exactamente con la parte fraccionada en el rango de memoria que tiene un float o un double. Es decir, el valor que tu asignas no es el mismo valor con que se trabaja internamente (más adelante un ejemplo)

Esto está presente también en javascript (y en la mayoría de los lenguajes)

```js
let value1 = 198.275;
let value2 = 273.275;

console.log( value1.toFixed(2));
console.log( value2.toFixed(2));
```

Y ahora observa si le damos 20 dígitos en la parte decimal

```js
let value1 = 198.275;
let value2 = 273.275;

console.log( value1.toFixed(20));
console.log( value2.toFixed(20));
```

Si le das a ejecutar, verás que NO da 198.2750000000000000000, que es lo que uno esperaría, si no que realmente hay otro número almacenado. Y al redondear este número puede existir una diferencia con el número real

¿La solución?

Simple, ocupar "decimal". El cual no soluciona del todo el problema, pero lo minimiza al extremo

```
decimal value1 = 198.275m;
decimal value2 = 273.275m;

Console.WriteLine("Round: " + Math.Round(value1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
Console.WriteLine("Round: " + Math.Round(value2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

Comment: Nunca dejamos de aprender... ¡Muchas gracias Yussef!