# ¿Por qué R se equivoca al calcular el residuo de dos números, por definición, divisibles entre sí?

Tags: r, programación-funcional, lenguaje-agnóstico, calculo, lenguaje-compilado

Me pasé el día de hoy explorando el campo de la geometría en general. En esa exploración, me topé con un video muy interesante de una exposición sobre la geometría no euclideana por parte del Doctor José María Montesinos Amilibia (cuya magistral clase recomiendo sobremanera). En medio de la exposición, dentro de los muchos temas que tocó, habló acerca de las formas que existen para demostrar un teorema. Una de estas, el llamado método "por absurdo".

Para ejemplificar el método, habló sobre el teorema de la infinitud de números primos, el cual, por método del absurdo puede ser demostrado asumiendo un escenario hipotético en el que los números primos son finitos. Los números primos entendidos como aquellos que son divisibles solamente entre sí y entre 1. Si partimos de ese escenario (absurdo) en el que los números primos son finitos (pero muchísimos) y los multiplicamos sucesivamente, digamos: `2 * 3 * 5 * 7` y seguimos multiplicando hasta llegar al billonésimo número primo que encontremos creyendo que hemos llegado al último. El resultado será, por lógica matemática, divisible entre todos los números primos que lo compusieron. Pero, al sumarle 1 a ese número, ese resultado + 1 será a su vez un número primo. Por tanto, se puede demostrar que los números primos son infinitos.

Habiendo contextualizado el origen de la cuestión, paso a la pregunta inicial. Pues, al abrir R para tratar de simular una multiplicación de números primos. Pude observar que al crear la siguiente variable `x <- 2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19*23*29*31*37*41*43*47` y utilizar el operador de residuo `%%` entre la variable `x` y cada uno de sus elementos constitutivos en la multiplicación, e.g. `x %% 2` o `x %% 29`, me llevé la sorpresa de que el resultado no fue el esperado `0` para cada uno de los elementos sino que a partir del `x %% 5` cuyo cálculo del residuo fue `2` todos los residuos calculados fueron diferentes a `0`.

Este resultado me llevó a cuestionarme, ¿por qué sucede este error de cálculo?,¿qué tanta atención deberíamos prestarle a esa evidente falta de precisión? y por último, ¿qué implicaciones podría tener esto en la ciencia que cada vez más se apoya en este tipo de lenguajes de programación para sus cálculos estadísticos y mediciones?

Saludos y espero que alguien pueda si no responder a cabalidad todas las preguntas, quizá, dar alguna luz sobre alguna de las cuestiones planteadas.

Comment: Entonces la pregunta es sobre R o en cualquier lenguaje?

Answer (score 0):

Nunca he usado `R`, pero si conozco muchos otros lenguajes y este problema es común en ellos, razón por la cual me atrevo a responder.

Aquí una demo en Javascript, donde tengo un array con los mismos números. Luego utilizo la función `reduce` para multiplicarlos y luego un `for` para aplicar el operador remanente, y tal como se puede apreciar sucede lo mismo que tu describes en tu pregunta.

```js
let primos=[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47];
const multiplicacion = primos.reduce((a,i)=> a*i);

for(let i of primos){
  console.log(multiplicacion%i);
}
```

Javascript al igual que R, son leguajes débilmente tipados, pero esto no quiere decir que no tenga un tipo, pues lo tienen. La mayoría de los lenguajes de programación asignan un tamaño fijo para almacenar números. Por ejemplo uno muy común es el entero de 32 bits.

A modo de ejemplo, diremos que existe un entero de 8bits, esto quiere decir que el número más grande que puedo almacenar es el `11111111` (en binario), equivalente al 255 en decimal y es lo mismo que 2<sup>8</sup>-1 y el más pequeño es cero, esto es para un tipo de dato sin signo. Cuando es con signo se emplea un bit para guardar ese signo (el de más a la izquierda), con lo cual podemos almacenar la misma cantidad de número pero en un rango diferente, para el caso de 8bits sería de -228 al 227

Y aquí viene el problema, cuando tu trabajas en un tipo de dato y te sales del rango ocurren cosas inesperadas, esto puede variar entre lenguajes. Algunos arrojan un error (que me parece lo adecuado) y otros simplemente dan resultados incorrectos, lo cual me parece peligroso ya que cualquiera puede confiarse en resultado.

Es decir, **tu problema radica en que el resultado de la multiplicación es un número muy grande y se escapa del tipo de dato que estas utilizando. Prueba con `x <- 2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19` y verás que el problema desaparece.**

*Como dato anecdótico: En las base de datos sucede lo mismo, y he sabido de un par de problemas en países con alta inflación donde se encontraron con problemas, ya que almacenaban enteros de 32bits que les permitía hasta 2.147.483.647 y que en un principio nadie se imaginó un presupuesto mayor a ese número, y luego ya era habitual*

La solución a este problema es usar otro tipo de número, los lenguajes modernos (o que han ido modernizándose), habtualmente han integrado un tipo de datos con mayor número de bits. Como te decía al principio, desconozco el caso particular de R, pero por ejemplo en javascript incluyeron el [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), aquí el mismo ejemplo usando BigInt (se usa con el sufijo `n`) donde se puede ver que el problema desaparece (**obviamente, también tiene un limite finito**)

```js
let primos=[2n,3n,5n,7n,11n,13n,17n,19n,23n,29n,31n,37n,41n,43n,47n];
const multiplicacion = BigInt(primos.reduce((a,i)=> a*i));

for(let i of primos){
  console.log( (multiplicacion%i).toString());
}
```

Ahora este no es el único problema, también tienes por ejemplo el [famoso error del punto flotante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/558876/301324) que se da en las fracciones.

---

Sobre tu pregunta final:

> ¿qué implicaciones podría tener esto en la ciencia que cada vez más se
> apoya en este tipo de lenguajes de programación para sus cálculos
> estadísticos y mediciones?

Evidentemente que tiene repercusiones, pero es que toda herramienta mal usada tiene el potencial de dar resultados nefastos.

Para mi el tema es otro: Todo lo que he escrito es lo básico de lo básico,  tanto así que recuerdo que esto lo vi en mi primera semana de Universidad. Este error debería ser muy poco común para un profesional con solidas bases.

Los que somos algo más viejos, los tipo de datos y la memoria que ocupaban era pan de cada día, es que debíamos asignar esa memoria a mano (y liberarla después de usarla). Lamentablemente, hoy veo que en muchas instituciones educacionales se saltan todo ese conocimiento (o lo tocan muy por arriba) y ahí donde está el peligro, por que tenemos nuevos profesionales sin conocimiento básico.

Por este motivo yo estoy muy en desacuerdo que a las nuevas generaciones (sobre todo en ciencias e ingeniería) comiencen con leguajes como python, javascript o incluso java donde estos conceptos son más difusos.

Answer (score 0):

El almacenamiento de cualquier número entero, o la parte decimal de uno, que tienda al infinito, requerirá un espacio de memoria que de igual forma tienda al infinito, el problema es que la disponibilidad de memoria de las cpus, aún si con los años fuera creciendo, siempre será limitada (hoy 32 o 64 bits). Esto significa que tenemos límites para poder almacenar números. Por una cuestión práctica, los lenguajes no tipados suelen usar por defecto algún formato de punto flotante, en el caso de R se usa el `double`, esto por que podes llevar el limite bastante más allá que el de un simple entero, a costa de perder  precisión, claro. Un número enorme termina representándose con un decimal y una potencia de 10. Esto:

```
primos <- c(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47)
prod(primos)

[1] 6.148898e+17
```

Es decir 6.148898 por 10 elevado a la 17, es decir 614.889.800.000.000.000, pero claramente no es el resultado preciso de este producto, por consiguiente el resto de la división con cada primo no necesariamente sea 0. ¿Es esto un problema? No, es un feature, de hecho es una solución muy ingeniosa diseñada en los comienzos de la informática para resolver el problema de como representar números más grandes de los que naturalmente el hardware podría representar y que se encuentra en cualquier "cacharro" electrónico que tenga que manejar números, hablo de la implementación, por que la notación exponencial existe y existió antes de la informática.

En definitiva, este tipo de cosas y otras similares ocurren cuando se trabaja con los tipos nativos de punto flotante de cada lenguaje. Por estas limitaciones hay librerías que permiten trabajar con número aún más grandes y con mayor precisión pero con costo de performance y recursos. En el caso de R tienes el paquete [gmp: Multiple Precision Arithmetic](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html)

```
library(gmp)
primos <- as.bigz(c(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47))
primos

Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 15:
 [1] 2  3  5  7  11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47

prod(primos)

Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 614889782588491410
```

Y con el resto:

```
prod(primos) %% primos

Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 15:
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```