# ¿Porque usar % en python me devuelve un numero con muchos decimales?

Tags: python, division

`print(5.1 % 3)` me devuelve `2.0999999999999996`,
`print(567.3 % 365)` me devuelve `202.29999999999995`, etc.
Quiero usar 365 para los años y el numero de dias no siempre es un numero entero.

Comment: Todos los años son de 365 o 366 días. Que a la tierra le tome un poco más de tiempo dar la vuelta completa al sol es otra cosa. Para corregir los desfases es que existen entre otras reglas, la de los años bisiestos. Esa es una cuestión culturales, por lo que la pregunta si la pregunta va sobre eso estaría fuera de tema.

Answer (score 2):

Estas calculando el módulo de un número real (con parte decimal), por lo que el resto no es  entero.

El operador % proporciona el resto de la división. Si también tienes la parte entera de la división, puedes reconstituir el valor original como:

```
valor = divisor * parte_entera + resto
```

Comprobemos el caso planteado: Tomemos el primer caso y calculemos la parte entera de la división

```
entero = 5.1 // 3 # => 1
```

y luego el resto:

```
resto = 5.1 % 3 # => 2.0999999999999996
```

Para comprar, calculemos el valor original en base a 3, la parte entera y el resto

```
recalculado = 3 * entero + resto # => 5.1
```

Los valores son correctos.

Comment: ¿Pero no deberia devolver 2.1?

Comment: @pabarmam. Debería, pero no da. Tampoco importa; la diferencia porcentual entre 2.1 y el resultado es 2.11 x 10^-14, o sea, cero.

Comment: @pabarmam Eso tiene que ver con el sistema de base 2 que usan los flotantes (ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/204/158880)). Si no querés ese "error de calculo" tendrás que usar (a costo de menor velocidad) el modulo [decimal](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/decimal.html). Nota: Cuando crees el numero, usa cadenas como "0.1", no flotantes.