# uso de double en for

Tags: bucle-for, double

porque al ejecutar estos dos segmentos de codigo

```
for (double x = 0.0; x <=1.2; x=x+0.1) {
    System.out.println(x);
}

while (a<=1.2){
    a=a+0.1;
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Las salidas son en mabos casos
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
1.0999999999999999
1.2
y no   0.0   0.1    02  0.3   0.4  etc   hasta llegar a 0.9  1.0  1.1 y 1.2
como deberia ser ???
eso es delicado si uno espera que en algun momento llege a 1.0 extact o y sin tanto
decimal de donde salen esas aproximaciones decimales?
o mejor si lo que se desea es sumar 0.1 y llegar a 1.0 como se haria entonces?

Comment: Eso es por cómo funcionan los números de punto flotante, es un comportamiento normal. Hay números finitos en decimal que no tienen una representación finita en binario y visceversa, lee este articulo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente

Comment: Si vas a manejar incrementos no deberías usar números con punto flotante.

Answer (score 2):

La aritmética de los valores de tipo `double` no otorga siempre valores precisos. Tal es tu caso, en el cual quieres incrementar los valores del bucle en `0.1`, dando como resultado datos errónes:

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
1.0999999999999999
1.2
```

Tienes dos veces lo que sería el valor `0.7`.

Una forma de evitar esto, es crear un bucle basado en números enteros, y hacer el incremento dentro del mismo, por ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    double d = 0.1 * i;
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

**Salida:**

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6000000000000001
0.7000000000000001
0.8
0.9
1.0
1.1
1.2000000000000002
```

Ahí sí ocurren los incrementos en intervalo de `0.1`, pero fíjate que aún haciendo eso, algunos valores se redondean distinto (puedes formatear a un punto decímal sin mayor dificultad) ...

PERO lo que es importante entender aquí es que la aritmética de redondeo con `double` es muyyyy complicada. Te recomiendo que para cada cosas que vayas a hacer uses el tipo de dato adecuado. Ni `double` ni `float` son recomendables en algunos casos, como trabajar con valores monetarios y otros.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que la mayoría de lenguajes de programación tienen problemas para trabajar con números decimales. [Este sitio web](https://betterprogramming.pub/why-is-0-1-0-2-not-equal-to-0-3-in-most-programming-languages-99432310d476) (en inglés) lo explica bastante bien. Te recomiendo que si quieres ejecutar tu código un determinado número de veces simplemente uses:

```js
// Mismo ejemplo en JavaScript
for (let i = 0; i <= 12; i+=1) {
  console.log('Este es el hola numero ' + i);
}
```

Comment: Hola Mateo, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboracíón, Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!