# Petición con .ajax tipo json recupera información con exceso de decimales que no fueron ingresados

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]no sé porque cuando grabo información de campos numericos tipo float en la base de datos, el registro se realiza tal y como se ingresó la información, pero cuando realizo una petición con .ajax tipo de datos json para realizar la edición y visualizarlos con DataTables en un formulario modal, se agregan automáticamente decimales que ni siquiera fueron grabados.

Los campos de Factor1, Factor2, Peso y Comisión fueron ingresados y estan grabados en la base de datos como: Factor1=0.6665 Factor2=1.6665 Peso=6.6 y Comisión 6. Porque al hacer la petición me regresan exceso de decimales ????

Comment: si guardaste un float, el numero que ves es correcto. mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente?r=Saves_AllUserSaves)

Comment: Pero puedes formatear los números antes de mostrarlos: parseFloat(numero).toFixed(2);