# ¿Hay alguna sugerencia para mejorar la estructura del código o hacer el cálculo de manera más eficiente?

Tags: javascript

Cuando ingreso un peso válido y hago clic en el botón de calcular, obtengo resultados inesperados. Parece que la lógica de cálculo no está produciendo los valores correctos. He revisado el código, pero no puedo identificar dónde está el error.

```
    function calcHollidaySegar(peso) {
    let flujo = 0;

    if (peso <= 10) {
      flujo = peso * 100;
    } else if (peso <= 20) {
      flujo = 10 * 100 + (peso - 10) * 50;
    } else {
      flujo = 10 * 100 + 10 * 50 + (peso - 20) * 20;
    }

      return flujo;
    }

    function calcSuperficieCorporal(peso) {
      let sc = ((peso * 4) + 7) / (parseInt(peso) + 90);
      let nElegido = 0;
      let flujo = 0;
      // Multiplicar por 1500 o 2000 según la preferencia del médico
      if(document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked){
         nElegido= document.getElementById('checkbox1').value;
      }else{
         nElegido= document.getElementById('checkbox2').value;
      }
         flujo = sc * nElegido;
         return flujo;
      }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. No solicites sugerencias, ya que preguntas de tal tipo terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Delimita siempre tu pregunta a un problema en particular. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/197)

Comment: Entonces el título de la pregunta debería ser *¿Por qué los cálculos dan mal?*, no *¿Cómo hacerlos más eficientes?* Si quieres ayuda, explica cuál debería ser el resultado para ciertos valores