# Redondeo de números negativos

Tags: python, redondeo

Estoy tratando de obtener un redondeo y al dividir el 0 entre un número negativo da como resultado -0, como puedo evitar eso? Necesito que el cero no tenga el signo negativo.

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP, ROUND_UP, ROUND_CEILING


cadena = ('-113146987 8258 -1365044733 -1616394 -875573453 28503 -604534216 -55792'
          ' -1280627493 8862474 -2030994863 -92831 918979986 -17177196 -589082593 -17233'
          ' 1045305370 95860 0 -11616 347237987 35158 0 41080')


cadena_lista = [x.strip() for x in cadena.split()]
#print(cadena_lista)


lista_nueva = []
for n in range(0, len(cadena_lista), 2):
    lista_nueva.append(cadena_lista[n:n+2])
#print(lista_nueva)


lista_enteros = [[int(n) for n in cadena_lista] for cadena_lista in lista_nueva]
print(lista_enteros)

resultados = []

for sublista in lista_enteros:
    resultado_sublista = Decimal(sublista[0] / sublista[1]).quantize(0, ROUND_HALF_UP)
    resultados.append(resultado_sublista)

resultado_finales = ' '.join(map(str, resultados))
print(resultado_finales)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué mis programas no pueden hacer cálculos aritméticos correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197/por-qu%c3%a9-mis-programas-no-pueden-hacer-c%c3%a1lculos-aritm%c3%a9ticos-correctamente)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El valor cero como tal no tiene signo en el ámbito matemático, pero como comentaron anteriormente en algunos lenguajes le ponen signo.

Lo curioso es que independientemente del signo, Python lo reconocerá como cero:

```
num1 = 0
num2 = 10
num3 = -10

result1 = num1/num2
result2 = num1/num3

print(result1, result2)
print(result1==0, result2==0)

0.0 -0.0
True True
```

La primera operación devuelve 0 positivo y la segunda cero negativo, pero al comprobar si ambos son iguales a cero positivo en ambos casos devuelve `True`

Sabiendo que Python va a reconocer el cero negativo como cero igualmente puedes forzar valor absoluto en tu código dentro de tu bucle `for` antes del `append`:

```
resultado_sublista = abs(resultado_sublista) if resultado_sublista==0 else resultado_sublista
```

Tu código ahora funciona así:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP, ROUND_UP, ROUND_CEILING

cadena = ('-113146987 8258 -1365044733 -1616394 -875573453 28503 -604534216 -55792'
          ' -1280627493 8862474 -2030994863 -92831 918979986 -17177196 -589082593 -17233'
          ' 1045305370 95860 0 -11616 347237987 35158 0 41080')


cadena_lista = [x.strip() for x in cadena.split()]
#print(cadena_lista)


lista_nueva = []
for n in range(0, len(cadena_lista), 2):
    lista_nueva.append(cadena_lista[n:n+2])
#print(lista_nueva)


lista_enteros = [[int(n) for n in cadena_lista] for cadena_lista in lista_nueva]
print(lista_enteros)

resultados = []

for sublista in lista_enteros:
    resultado_sublista = Decimal(sublista[0] / sublista[1]).quantize(0, ROUND_HALF_UP)
    resultado_sublista = abs(resultado_sublista) if resultado_sublista==0 else resultado_sublista
    resultados.append(resultado_sublista)

resultado_finales = ' '.join(map(str, resultados))
print(resultado_finales)

[[-113146987, 8258], [-1365044733, -1616394], [-875573453, 28503], [-604534216, -55792], [-1280627493, 8862474], [-2030994863, -92831], [918979986, -17177196], [-589082593, -17233], [1045305370, 95860], [0, -11616], [347237987, 35158], [0, 41080]]
-13702 845 -30719 10836 -145 21878 -54 34183 10905 0 9877 0
```

Comment: Un detalle, no hay nada de curioso en que `-0==0` es parte del estándar

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! Ahora sí se obtuvo el resultado esperado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

El problema que encontraste se debe a la representación del cero en sistemas numéricos con signo. En muchos lenguajes de programación, incluido `Python`, los enteros suelen ser con signo, lo que significa que pueden ser positivos o negativos. El cero se considera ni positivo ni negativo, pero aún así tiene un signo.

Cuando realizas operaciones aritméticas que resultan en cero, podrías obtener un resultado con un signo negativo, dependiendo de los signos de los operandos involucrados. Por ejemplo, si divides un número negativo entre un número positivo, obtienes un resultado negativo.

Ejemplo simple para comprobar lo dicho:

```
a = 1
b = -1
z = 0

print(z/a, z/b)
```

Esto imprime lo siguiente:

```
0.0 -0.0
```

En tu caso, cuando realizaste la división y cuantificaste el resultado a cero decimales, esencialmente redondeaste cualquier resultado negativo pequeño a `-0`.

Lo que puedes hacer para "corregir" este comportamiento es convertir el resultado obtenido a entero usando `int()`.

```
resultado_sublista = int(resultado_sublista.quantize(Decimal('1.'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP))
```

De esta forma tu código imprimiría lo siguiente:

```
[[-113146987, 8258], [-1365044733, -1616394], [-875573453, 28503], [-604534216, -55792], [-1280627493, 8862474], [-2030994863, -92831], [918979986, -17177196], [-589082593, -17233], [1045305370, 95860], [0, -11616], [347237987, 35158], [0, 41080]]
-13702 845 -30719 10836 -145 21878 -54 34183 10905 0 9877 0
```

Comment: He realizado los cambios sugeridos @HeytalePazguato y me da un error... resultado_sublista = int(resultado_sublista.quantize(Decimal('1.'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP))
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'quantize'